# How can I pass arguments to a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, arguments

I need to pass an ID and a password to a batch file at the time of running rather than hardcoding them into the file.

Here's what the command line looks like:

```
test.cmd admin P@55w0rd > test-log.txt
```

Comment: For "all the rest" see Greg Hegill's comment at [how to get batch file parameters from Nth position on?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/382587/how-to-get-batch-file-parameters-from-nth-position-on)

Comment: I have an environment startup script that will push my username/password into environment variables... so that I don't have to type them out each time... I'm using bash most of the time though (linux, mac and windows), and need to use it for proxy configs in scripts, etc for work.

Answer (score 358, accepted):

Here's how I did it:

```
@fake-command /u %1 /p %2
```

Here's what the command looks like:

```
test.cmd admin P@55w0rd > test-log.txt
```

The `%1` applies to the first parameter the `%2` (and here's the tricky part) applies to the second. You can have up to 9 parameters passed in this way.

Comment: If you're as dumb as me, your mind was looking for `echo %1 %2` and was thrown off by the non cut-and-pasteable simplest case with a `@` and a `fake-command` with params, thinking we'd get `fake-command.bat`'s contents later (in which case, the overcomplicated `fake-command.bat` might have `echo %2 %4` to ignore the param names). *Wrong, doofus.* **TL;DR: Don't be as dumb as me.** 1. `echo echo %1 %2 > test.bat` 2. `test word1 word2`. 3. Profit.

Comment: Five years later, I'm back reading my comment w/ confusion. Seem to have meant "to create a .bat with two parameters, literally type `echo echo %1 %2 > test.bat`. The test.bat file will have `echo %1 %2` in it (you could've also saved it from a text editor). Now type `test word1 word2` to call & see the parameters worked. `word1 word2` will be echoed to the command line. (`echo %2 %4` would've ignored `/u` and `/p` so you could've called `test /u word1 /p word2` to get the same result). [`@` before a cmd in a bat file means the cmd isn't repeated.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21077142/1028230)

Comment: You might want some quote handling/protection too, e.g.:

SetLocal

Set dbName=%1

Rem dbName

If Not Defined dbName  Goto SyntaxErr

REM  Remove all (/any) the quotes
Set dbName=%dbName:"=%

If "%dbName%" == ""  Goto SyntaxErr

Answer (score 1285):

Another useful tip is to use `%*` to mean "all". For example:

```
echo off
set arg1=%1
set arg2=%2
shift
shift
fake-command /u %arg1% /p %arg2% %*
```

When you run:

```
test-command admin password foo bar
```

The above batch file will run:

```
fake-command /u admin /p password admin password foo bar
```

I may have the syntax slightly wrong, but this is the general idea.

Comment: %* actually expands to all parameters regardless of shift. So even after the two shifts you would still have the first two arguments in %*. You can use something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761615/is-there-a-way-to-indicate-the-last-n-parameters-in-a-batch-file/761658#761658 to get a variable that contains everything but the first n parameters.

Comment: Please note that %* does not work everywhere! For instance, it does not work with DOSBox 0.73 (maybe this is a bug that should be reported).

Comment: It's not a bug because %* never worked in MS-DOS or Win9x in the first place.

Comment: I think `shift` "pops" the argument from the list. The assumption by OP was that `%*` would only output the remaining arguments, but it doesn't work that way, as @Joey said.

Comment: This answer is wrong.  It actually results in `fake-command /u admin /p password admin password foo bar`.  This was pointed out by @Joey many years ago.

Comment: The two shifts are pointless in this case. AFTER them %1 would become foo and %2 would become bar but this is not used in any way and %* is not affected by the shift command

Comment: what does fake-command do or what does it mean ?

Answer (score 177):

If you want to intelligently handle missing parameters you can do something like:

```
IF %1.==. GOTO No1
IF %2.==. GOTO No2
... do stuff...
GOTO End1

:No1
  ECHO No param 1
GOTO End1
:No2
  ECHO No param 2
GOTO End1

:End1
```

Comment: What's the significance of dot/period in these equality operations?

Comment: Basically if %1 is empty, this will end up being IF . == . and so the GOTO will happen. We use x here so: IF x%1 == x -> IF x==x -> true

Comment: You should aks for what is the value of a "unprovided argument"? Againts what you should check an "unprovided argument"? 

Then, if you don't have an answer, you should use a trick like the one of the dots. Remember that, like stated here  https://ss64.com/nt/if.html "You can in fact use almost any character for this a '~' or curly brackets, { } or even the number 4, but square brackets tend to be chosen because they don't have any special meaning."

Answer (score 102):

Accessing batch parameters can be simple with %1, %2, ... %9 or also %*,
but only if the content is simple.

There is no simple way for complex contents like `"&"^&`, as it's not possible to access %1 without producing an error.

```
set  var=%1
set "var=%1"
set  var=%~1
set "var=%~1"
```

The lines expand to

```
set  var="&"&
set "var="&"&"
set  var="&"&
set "var="&"&"
```

And each line fails, as one of the `&` is outside of the quotes.

It can be solved with reading from a temporary file a **remarked** version of the parameter.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion

SETLOCAL
for %%a in (1) do (
    set "prompt="
    echo on
    for %%b in (1) do rem * #%1#
    @echo off
) > param.txt
ENDLOCAL

for /F "delims=" %%L in (param.txt) do (
  set "param1=%%L"
)
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set "param1=!param1:*#=!"
set "param1=!param1:~0,-2!"
echo %%1 is '!param1!'
```

The trick is to enable `echo on` and expand the %1 after a `rem` statement (works also with `%2 .. %*`).
So even `"&"&` could be echoed without producing an error, as it is remarked.

But to be able to redirect the output of the `echo on`, you need the two for-loops.

The extra characters `* #` are used to be safe against contents like `/?` (would show the help for `REM`).
Or a caret ^ at the line end could work as a multiline character, even in after a `rem`.

Then reading the **rem parameter** output from the file, but carefully.
The FOR /F should work with delayed expansion off, else contents with "!" would be destroyed.
After removing the extra characters in `param1`, you got it.

And to use `param1` in a safe way, enable the delayed expansion.

Comment: for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('echo %*') do set "all_args=%%a"

Comment: @KevinEdwards Then try it with one `&`, your solution works only with simple content

Comment: @KevinEdwards I tested it, `test.bat ^&` and it fails. Only `test.bat "&"` works, but that wasn't my point. You can't use `%*`, `%1` in a safe way without the REM technic

Comment: Ah, yes, a caret doesn't escape it properly.  You need quotes, which is feasible for all the use cases I've come across.  I just wanted to pass it along.  Thanks for testing it!  Cheers :)

Comment: I have a concern about this method (echo-on-and-rem-piped-to-a-file trick): Although batch and cmd.exe don't allow newlines in command arguments, but for shells that allow it when calling the script, the trick **breaks**. And don't laugh, because PowerShell allow newlines in arguments. Using low-level [CreateProcess()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) function is also possible to make a newline and break it.

Comment: @Explorer09 Batch and also cmd.exe allowes both newlines in arguments, but it's tricky. The `echo-on-and-rem-redirect-to-a-file trick` can also fetch multiline arguments, but that isn't bullet proof, see [SO:...multi line text as argument...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42880266/463115)

Comment: @jeb The SO answer you mentioned does allow multi-line argument parsing, but doesn't protect against command injection from line 2 and onward. I fear there will be no true bullet-proof solution until there's an extension syntax (e.g. `!1!` `!2!` or `!!1` `!!2`) that can truly delay-expand the arguments.

Comment: Over complicated and mostly not directly related the OP's question.

Comment: @jwdonahue Yes, it's complicated (but not over complicated). But especially for passwords it could be necessary, at least some of my passwords contain ampersands  `&` and also quotes `"`

Comment: @Explorer09 Some time ago, I developed another technique to retrieve even any multi-line arguments, it's safe against injection. See [syntax-error-technic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55689910/463115)

Answer (score 72):

This technique has a bit of an overhead as you'll see, but it makes my batch files very easy to understand and quick to implement. As well as supporting the following structures:

```
>template.bat [-f] [--flag] [--namedvalue value] arg1 [arg2][arg3][...]
```

The jist of it is having the `:init`, `:parse`, and `:main` functions.

### template.bat

```
@::!/dos/rocks
@echo off
goto :init

:header
    echo %__NAME% v%__VERSION%
    echo This is a sample batch file template,
    echo providing command-line arguments and flags.
    echo.
    goto :eof

:usage
    echo USAGE:
    echo   %__BAT_NAME% [flags] "required argument" "optional argument" 
    echo.
    echo.  /?, --help           shows this help
    echo.  /v, --version        shows the version
    echo.  /e, --verbose        shows detailed output
    echo.  -f, --flag value     specifies a named parameter value
    goto :eof

:version
    if "%~1"=="full" call :header & goto :eof
    echo %__VERSION%
    goto :eof

:missing_argument
    call :header
    call :usage
    echo.
    echo ****    MISSING "REQUIRED ARGUMENT"    ****
    echo.
    goto :eof

:init
    set "__NAME=%~n0"
    set "__VERSION=1.24"
    set "__YEAR=2023"

    set "__BAT_FILE=%~0"
    set "__BAT_PATH=%~dp0"
    set "__BAT_NAME=%~nx0"

    set "OptHelp="
    set "OptVersion="
    set "OptVerbose="

    set "UnNamedArgument="
    set "UnNamedOptionalArg="
    set "NamedFlag="

:parse
    if "%~1"=="" goto :validate

    if /i "%~1"=="/?"         call :header & call :usage "%~2" & goto :end
    if /i "%~1"=="-?"         call :header & call :usage "%~2" & goto :end
    if /i "%~1"=="--help"     call :header & call :usage "%~2" & goto :end

    if /i "%~1"=="/v"         call :version      & goto :end
    if /i "%~1"=="-v"         call :version      & goto :end
    if /i "%~1"=="--version"  call :version full & goto :end

    if /i "%~1"=="/e"         set "OptVerbose=yes"  & shift & goto :parse
    if /i "%~1"=="-e"         set "OptVerbose=yes"  & shift & goto :parse
    if /i "%~1"=="--verbose"  set "OptVerbose=yes"  & shift & goto :parse

    if /i "%~1"=="--flag"     set "NamedFlag=%~2"   & shift & shift & goto :parse
    if /i "%~1"=="-f"         set "NamedFlag=%~2"   & shift & shift & goto :parse

    if not defined UnNamedArgument     set "UnNamedArgument=%~1"     & shift & goto :parse
    if not defined UnNamedOptionalArg  set "UnNamedOptionalArg=%~1"  & shift & goto :parse

    shift
    goto :parse

:validate
    if not defined UnNamedArgument call :missing_argument & goto :end

:main
    if defined OptVerbose (
        echo **** DEBUG IS ON
    )

    echo UnNamedArgument:    "%UnNamedArgument%"

    if defined UnNamedOptionalArg      echo UnNamedOptionalArg: "%UnNamedOptionalArg%"
    if not defined UnNamedOptionalArg  echo UnNamedOptionalArg: not provided

    if defined NamedFlag               echo NamedFlag:          "%NamedFlag%"
    if not defined NamedFlag           echo NamedFlag:          not provided

:end
    call :cleanup
    exit /B

:cleanup
    REM The cleanup function is only really necessary if you
    REM are _not_ using SETLOCAL.
    set "__NAME="
    set "__VERSION="
    set "__YEAR="

    set "__BAT_FILE="
    set "__BAT_PATH="
    set "__BAT_NAME="

    set "OptHelp="
    set "OptVersion="
    set "OptVerbose="

    set "UnNamedArgument="
    set "UnNamedArgument2="
    set "NamedFlag="

    goto :eof
```

| Example usage | returns |
| --- | --- |
| template.bat | template v1.24 This is a sample batch file template, providing command-line arguments and flags. USAGE: template.bat [flags] "required argument" "optional argument" /?, --help shows this help /v, --version shows the version /e, --verbose shows detailed output -f, --flag value specifies a named parameter value **** MISSING "REQUIRED ARGUMENT" **** |
| template.bat /? | template v1.24 This is a sample batch file template, providing command-line arguments and flags. USAGE: template.bat [flags] "required argument" "optional argument" /?, --help shows this help /v, --version shows the version /e, --verbose shows detailed output -f, --flag value specifies a named parameter value |
| template.bat --v | 1.24 |
| template.bat --version | template v1.24 This is a sample batch file template, providing command-line arguments and flags. |
| template.bat -e arg1 | **** DEBUG IS ON UnNamedArgument: "arg1" UnNamedOptionalArg: not provided NamedFlag: not provided |
| template.bat --flag "my flag" arg1 arg2 *(without -e)* | UnNamedArgument: "arg1" UnNamedOptionalArg: "arg2" NamedFlag: "my flag" |
| template.bat --verbose "argument #1" --flag "my flag" second | **** DEBUG IS ON UnNamedArgument: "argument #1" UnNamedOptionalArg: "second" NamedFlag: "my flag" |

Comment: What a piece of beauty! For future readers, I only want to highlight that the `-f` flag is not actually included in the parse-section yet. Just a heads up!

Comment: I accepted your edit @Flo. Thanks!

Comment: What does the first line, `@::!/dos/rocks`?, do?

Comment: It is a commented line, so it does nothing. It's just for fun! Bash scripts have the shebang, so I started using that for my batch files. ;) (I know the shebang is actually instructions..)

Comment: This is amazing! Perfect after looking up an approach to have one singular file for bash and batch as mentioned from this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48938482/13642249).

Comment: you've covered everything. Great answer.

Answer (score 65):

Yep, and just don't forget to use variables like `%%1` when using `if` and `for` and the gang.

If you forget the double `%`, then you will be substituting in (possibly null) command line arguments and you will receive some pretty confusing error messages.

Comment: %% is only for `if` and `for` ?

Comment: It's worse than that - %% is used to prefix variables and command line parameters *inside* batch files. But when you use these commands from the command line, you use only % to prefix. Example: inside batch: `for %%d in (*) do echo %%d` from command line: `for %d in (*) do echo %d`

Comment: @SteveMidgley I upvoted your comment probably a year or so ago. I then promptly forgot about it and just today I was trying and staring confusingly at my for loop in the command line and wondering why it farted and did nothing else. So here's another virtual upvote from me. I'll be back in another year or so when I hit the same issue again.

Comment: We usually reserve the digits for command line processing and the double percent only applies to the for statement as far as I know.  `@for %%2 in (testing) do @echo %%2 %1` in a batch file, produces `testing 1` when it is called with 1 (`test 1`).

Comment: The answer is wrong. `%%1` doesn't access a command line argument, and it's also wrong for the `IF` command. Only the `FOR` command (in batch files) requires double percents, but even then `%%1` would define a FOR parameter and doesn't access arguments

Answer (score 56):

There is no need to complicate it. It is simply command %1 %2 parameters, for example,

```
@echo off

xcopy %1 %2 /D /E /C /Q /H /R /K /Y /Z

echo copied %1 to %2

pause
```

The "pause" displays what the batch file has done and waits for you to hit the ANY key. Save that as xx.bat in the Windows folder.

To use it, type, for example:

```
xx c:\f\30\*.* f:\sites\30
```

This batch file takes care of all the necessary parameters, like copying only files, that are newer, etc. I have used it since before Windows. If you like seeing the names of the files, as they are being copied, leave out the `Q` parameter.

Answer (score 42):

Everyone has answered with really complex responses, however it is actually really simple. `%1 %2 %3` and so on are the arguements parsed to the file. `%1` is arguement 1, `%2` is arguement 2 and so on.

So, if I have a bat script containing this:

```sh
@echo off
echo %1
```

and when I run the batch script, I type in this:

```
C:> script.bat Hello
```

The script will simply output this:

```
Hello
```

This can be very useful for certain variables in a script, such as a name and age. So, if I have a script like this:

```sh
@echo off
echo Your name is: %1
echo Your age is: %2
```

When I type in this:

```
C:> script.bat Oliver 1000
```

I get the output of this:

```
Your name is: Oliver
Your age is: 1000
```

Comment: Great answer. Concise and easy to follow. 

Comment: how would you handle string variables that have spaces?

Answer (score 38):

In batch file

```
set argument1=%1
set argument2=%2
echo %argument1%
echo %argument2%
```

`%1` and `%2` return the first and second argument values respectively.

And in command line, pass the argument

```
Directory> batchFileName admin P@55w0rd
```

Output will be

```
admin
P@55w0rd
```

Answer (score 33):

```
@ECHO OFF
:Loop
IF "%1"=="" GOTO Continue
SHIFT
GOTO Loop
:Continue
```

Note:   IF `"%1"==""` will cause problems if `%1` is enclosed in quotes itself.

In that case, use `IF [%1]==[]` or, in NT 4 (SP6) and later only, `IF "%~1"==""` instead.

Comment: True enough, but it barely touches the subject matter.

Answer (score 26):

Let's keep this simple.

Here is the .cmd file.

```
@echo off
rem this file is named echo_3params.cmd
echo %1
echo %2
echo %3
set v1=%1
set v2=%2
set v3=%3
echo v1 equals %v1%
echo v2 equals %v2%
echo v3 equals %v3%
```

Here are 3 calls from the command line.

```
C:\Users\joeco>echo_3params 1abc 2 def  3 ghi
1abc
2
def
v1 equals 1abc
v2 equals 2
v3 equals def

C:\Users\joeco>echo_3params 1abc "2 def"  "3 ghi"
1abc
"2 def"
"3 ghi"
v1 equals 1abc
v2 equals "2 def"
v3 equals "3 ghi"

C:\Users\joeco>echo_3params 1abc '2 def'  "3 ghi"
1abc
'2
def'
v1 equals 1abc
v2 equals '2
v3 equals def'

C:\Users\joeco>
```

Comment: I know, a long time ago.  But thank you! Simple is best, we can figure out the rest. Huh, a poem.

Comment: "Simple is best, we can figure out the rest"! Words to live by. Thanks, Alan.

Answer (score 22):

```
FOR %%A IN (%*) DO (
    REM Now your batch file handles %%A instead of %1
    REM No need to use SHIFT anymore.
    ECHO %%A
)
```

This loops over the batch parameters (%*) either they are quoted or not, then echos each parameter.

Comment: But fails with many different arguments, like  `test.bat *.txt`, `test.bat cat^&dog` or `Test.bat /?`

Answer (score 21):

I wrote a simple read_params script that can be called as a function (or external `.bat`) and will put all variables into the current environment. It won't modify the original parameters because the function is being `call`ed with a copy of the original parameters.

For example, given the following command:

```
myscript.bat some -random=43 extra -greeting="hello world" fluff
```

`myscript.bat` would be able to use the variables after calling the function:

```
call :read_params %*

echo %random%
echo %greeting%
```

Here's the function:

```
:read_params
if not %1/==/ (
    if not "%__var%"=="" (
        if not "%__var:~0,1%"=="-" (
            endlocal
            goto read_params
        )
        endlocal & set %__var:~1%=%~1
    ) else (
        setlocal & set __var=%~1
    )
    shift
    goto read_params
)
exit /B
```

---

**Limitations**

- Cannot load arguments with no value such as `-force`. You could use `-force=true` but I can't think of a way to allow blank values without knowing a list of parameters ahead of time that won't have a value.

---

**Changelog**

- **2/18/2016**

  - No longer requires delayed expansion
  - Now works with other command line arguments by looking for `-` before parameters.

Comment: Been looking at using this method as I would like to pass arguments into a batch file in this manner. However I notice that after the variables are set, even after exiting the batch file the parameters are still set in the cmd if accessed and the batch has ended, they are not restored to their previous state. Should this method handle that situation?

Comment: On topic and better than some of the rest of the answers on this thread.

Comment: Extended it to support flag args (without values). Sorry for lack of formatting but it doesn't work in comments

:read_params
if not %1/==/ (
    if not "%__var%"=="" (
        if not "%__var:~0,1%"=="-" (
            endlocal
            goto read_params
        )
        endlocal & set %__var:~1%=%~1
    ) else (
        setlocal & set __var=%~1
    )
    shift
    goto read_params
) else (
    if not "%__var%"=="" (
        endlocal & set %__var:~1%=1
    )
)

Answer (score 13):

Inspired by an [answer elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14298769/421049) by @Jon, I have crafted a more general algorithm for extracting named parameters, optional values, and switches.

Let us say that we want to implement a utility `foobar`. It requires an initial command. It has an optional parameter `--foo` which takes an *optional* value (which cannot be another parameter, of course); if the value is missing it defaults to `default`. It also has an optional parameter `--bar` which takes a *required* value. Lastly it can take a flag `--baz` with no value allowed. Oh, and these parameters can come in any order.

In other words, it looks like this:

```
foobar <command> [--foo [<fooval>]] [--bar <barval>] [--baz]
```

Here is a solution:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
REM FooBar parameter demo
REM By Garret Wilson

SET CMD=%~1

IF "%CMD%" == "" (
  GOTO usage
)
SET FOO=
SET DEFAULT_FOO=default
SET BAR=
SET BAZ=

SHIFT
:args
SET PARAM=%~1
SET ARG=%~2
IF "%PARAM%" == "--foo" (
  SHIFT
  IF NOT "%ARG%" == "" (
    IF NOT "%ARG:~0,2%" == "--" (
      SET FOO=%ARG%
      SHIFT
    ) ELSE (
      SET FOO=%DEFAULT_FOO%
    )
  ) ELSE (
    SET FOO=%DEFAULT_FOO%
  )
) ELSE IF "%PARAM%" == "--bar" (
  SHIFT
  IF NOT "%ARG%" == "" (
    SET BAR=%ARG%
    SHIFT
  ) ELSE (
    ECHO Missing bar value. 1>&2
    ECHO:
    GOTO usage
  )
) ELSE IF "%PARAM%" == "--baz" (
  SHIFT
  SET BAZ=true
) ELSE IF "%PARAM%" == "" (
  GOTO endargs
) ELSE (
  ECHO Unrecognized option %1. 1>&2
  ECHO:
  GOTO usage
)
GOTO args
:endargs

ECHO Command: %CMD%
IF NOT "%FOO%" == "" (
  ECHO Foo: %FOO%
)
IF NOT "%BAR%" == "" (
  ECHO Bar: %BAR%
)
IF "%BAZ%" == "true" (
  ECHO Baz
)

REM TODO do something with FOO, BAR, and/or BAZ
GOTO :eof

:usage
ECHO FooBar
ECHO Usage: foobar ^<command^> [--foo [^<fooval^>]] [--bar ^<barval^>] [--baz]
EXIT /B 1
```

- Use `SETLOCAL` so that the variables don't escape into the calling environment.
- Don't forget to initialize the variables `SET FOO=`, etc. in case someone defined them in the calling environment.
- Use `%~1` to remove quotes.
- Use `IF "%ARG%" == ""` and not `IF [%ARG%] == []` because `[` and `]` don't play will at all with values ending in a space.
- Even if you `SHIFT` inside an `IF` block, the current args such as `%~1` don't get updated because they are determined when the `IF` is parsed. You could use `%~1` and `%~2` inside the `IF` block, but it would be confusing because you had a `SHIFT`. You could put the `SHIFT` at the end of the block for clarity, but that might get lost and/or confuse people as well. So "capturing" `%~1` and `%~1` outside the block seems best.
- You don't want to use a parameter in place of another parameter's optional value, so you have to check `IF NOT "%ARG:~0,2%" == "--"`.
- Be careful only to `SHIFT` when you *use* one of the parameters.
- The duplicate code `SET FOO=%DEFAULT_FOO%` is regrettable, but the alternative would be to add an `IF "%FOO%" == "" SET FOO=%DEFAULT_FOO%` outside the `IF NOT "%ARG%" == ""` block. However because this is still inside the `IF "%PARAM%" == "--foo"` block, the `%FOO%` value would have been evaluated and set before you ever entered the block, so you would never detect that *both* the `--foo` parameter was present *and also* that the `%FOO%` value was missing.
- Note that `ECHO Missing bar value. 1>&2` sends the error message to stderr.
- Want a blank line in a Windows batch file? You gotta use `ECHO:` or one of the variations.

Answer (score 10):

To refer to a set variable in command line you would need to use `%a%` so for example:

```
set a=100 
echo %a%  
rem output = 100
```

Note: This works for Windows 7 pro.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

> *For to use looping get all arguments and in pure batch:*

**Obs:** For using without: **`?*&|<>`**

---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

 for %%Z in (%*)do set "_arg_=%%Z" && set/a "_cnt+=1+0" && (
     call set "_arg_[!_cnt!]=!_arg_!" && for /l %%l in (!_cnt! 1 !_cnt!
     )do echo/ The argument n:%%l is: !_arg_[%%l]!
 )

endlocal
```

> *Your code is ready to do something with the argument number where it needs, like...*

```bat
 @echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

 for %%Z in (%*)do set "_arg_=%%Z" && set/a "_cnt+=1+0" && call set "_arg_[!_cnt!]=!_arg_!"
 
 fake-command /u !_arg_[1]! /p !_arg_[2]! > test-log.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution(even though question is old)

Test1.bat

```
echo off
echo "Batch started"
set arg1=%1
echo "arg1 is %arg1%"
echo on
pause
```

CallTest1.bat

```
call "C:\Temp\Test1.bat" pass123
```

output

```
YourLocalPath>call "C:\Temp\test.bat" pass123

YourLocalPath>echo off
"Batch started"
"arg1 is pass123"

YourLocalPath>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Where YourLocalPath is current directory path.

To keep things simple store the command param in variable and use variable for comparison.

Its not just simple to write but its simple to maintain as well so if later some other person or you read your script after long period of time, it will be easy to understand and maintain.

To write code inline : see other answers.

Answer (score 3):

Make a new batch file (example: openclass.bat) and write this line in the file:

```
java %~n1
```

Then place the batch file in, let's say, the system32 folder, go to your Java class file, right click, Properties, Open with..., then find your batch file, select it and that's that...

It works for me.

PS: I can't find a way to close the cmd window when I close the Java class. For now...

Comment: You can close the cmd window after the process has closed using the following command in a batch script:
`start /wait java %~n1`

Comment: Advising the public to put random script files in the system32 directory is irresponsible.  This answer really doesn't scratch the surface of the topic of this thread.

Answer (score 2):

### Paired arguments

If you prefer passing the arguments in a key-value pair you can use something like this:

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:::::  asigning arguments as a key-value pairs:::::::::::::
set counter=0
for %%# in (%*) do (    
    set /a counter=counter+1
    set /a even=counter%%2
    
    if !even! == 0 (
        echo setting !prev! to %%#
        set "!prev!=%%~#"
    )
    set "prev=%%~#"
)
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:: showing the assignments
echo %one% %two% %three% %four% %five%

endlocal
```

And an example :

```
c:>argumentsDemo.bat one 1 "two" 2 three 3 four 4 "five" 5
1 2 3 4 5
```

### Predefined variables

You can also set some environment variables in advance. It can be done by setting them in the console or [setting them from my computer](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm):

```
@echo off

if defined variable1 (
    echo %variable1%
)

if defined variable2 (
    echo %variable2%
)
```

and calling it like:

```
c:\>set variable1=1

c:\>set variable2=2

c:\>argumentsTest.bat
1
2
```

### File with listed values

You can also point to a file where the needed values are preset.
If this is the script:

```
@echo off

setlocal
::::::::::
set "VALUES_FILE=E:\scripts\values.txt"
:::::::::::


for /f "usebackq eol=: tokens=* delims=" %%# in ("%VALUES_FILE%") do set "%%#"

echo %key1% %key2% %some_other_key%

endlocal
```

and values file is this:

```
:::: use EOL=: in the FOR loop to use it as a comment

key1=value1

key2=value2

:::: do not left spaces arround the =
:::: or at the begining of the line

some_other_key=something else

and_one_more=more
```

the output of calling it will be:

> value1 value2 something else

Of course you can combine all approaches. Check also [arguments syntax](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) , [shift](https://ss64.com/nt/shift.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about security/password theft (that led you to design this solution that takes login credentials at execution instead of static hard coding without the need for a database), then you could store the api or half the code of password decryption or decryption key in the program file, so at run time, user would type username/password in console to be hashed/decrypted before passed to program code for execution via `set /p`, if you're looking at user entering credentials at run time.

If you're running a script to run your program with various user/password, then command line args will suit you.

If you're making a test file to see the output/effects of different logins, then you could store all the logins in an encrypted file, to be passed as arg to test.cmd, unless you wanna sit at command line & type all the logins until finished.

The number of args that can be supplied is [limited to total characters on command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/shell-experience/command-line-string-limitation). To overcome this limitation, the previous paragraph trick is a workaround without risking exposure of user passwords.