# how to get batch file parameters from Nth position on?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Further to [How to Pass Command Line Parameters in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-to-pass-command-line-parameters-in-batch-file) how does one get the rest of the parameters with specifying them exactly? I don't want to use SHIFT because I don't know how many parameters there might be and would like to avoid counting them, if I can.

For example, given this batch file:

```
@echo off
set par1=%1
set par2=%2
set par3=%3
set therest=%???
echo the script is %0
echo Parameter 1 is %par1%
echo Parameter 2 is %par2%
echo Parameter 3 is %par3%
echo and the rest are %therest%
```

Running `mybatch opt1 opt2 opt3 opt4 opt5 ...opt20` would yield:

```
the script is mybatch
Parameter 1 is opt1
Parameter 2 is opt2
Parameter 3 is opt3
and the rest are opt4 opt5 ...opt20
```

I know `%*` gives all the parameters, but I don't wan't the first three (for example).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to indicate the last n parameters in a batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761615/is-there-a-way-to-indicate-the-last-n-parameters-in-a-batch-file)

Comment: [callshift.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9363080/how-to-make-shift-work-with-in-batch-files/77744044#77744044)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here's how you can do it without using `SHIFT`:

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=1-3*" %%a in ("%*") do (
    set par1=%%a
    set par2=%%b
    set par3=%%c
    set therest=%%d
)

echo the script is %0
echo Parameter 1 is %par1%
echo Parameter 2 is %par2%
echo Parameter 3 is %par3%
echo and the rest are %therest%
```

Comment: This probably won't handle parameters enclosed in quotation marks correctly.

Comment: Johannes left a solid answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761615/is-there-a-way-to-indicate-the-last-n-parameters-in-a-batch-file

Comment: @Dave; what's not solid abut this answer?

Comment: @PatrickCuff If you run your batch file with quoted parameters with spaces in them, the output will be wrong. Try these 6 for example: "param 1" "param 2" "param 3" 4 5 6

Comment: Both have multiple issues. Try to forward parameters like `--path=c:\a\b\c`. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49040793/468725) that handles these these cases better.

Answer (score 5):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set therest=;;;;;%*
set therest=!therest:;;;;;%1 %2 %3 =!

echo the script is %0
echo Parameter 1 is %1
echo Parameter 2 is %2
echo Parameter 3 is %3
echo and the rest are: %therest%
```

This works with quoted arguments and with arguments that have equal signs or commas, as long as first three arguments didn't have these special delimiter chars.

Sample output:

```
test_args.bat "1 1 1" 2 3 --a=b "x y z"
Parameter 1 is "1 1 1"
Parameter 2 is 2
Parameter 3 is 3
and the rest are: --a=b "x y z"
```

This works by replacing `%1 %2 %3` in original command line `%*`. The first five semicolons are there just to make sure that only the first occurrence of these `%1 %2 %3` is replaced.

Comment: On the off chance that there are more than 1 space b/w the parameters to be skipped (i.e. %1 %2 %3 in this example) this could also fail (since the string replacement would not work). In other words, for this to work as expected, the batch should be called properly, with a single space b/w parameters. Also, first 3 parameters should not contain an equal sign.

Answer (score 1):

The following code uses `shift`, but it avoids to parse the command line using `for` and lets the command line interpreter do this job (regard that `for` does not parse double-quotes properly, for instance argument set `A B" "C` is interpreted as 3 arguments `A`, `B"`, `"C` by `for`, but as 2 arguments `A`, `B" "C` by the interpreter; this behaviour prevents quoted path arguments like `"C:\Program Files\"` from being handled correctly):

```
@echo off

set "par1=%1" & shift /1
set "par2=%1" & shift /1
set "par3=%1" & shift /1

set therest=
set delim=

:REPEAT
if "%1"=="" goto :UNTIL
set "therest=%therest%%delim%%1"
set "delim= "
shift /1
goto :REPEAT
:UNTIL

echo the script is "%0"
echo Parameter 1 is "%par1%"
echo Parameter 2 is "%par2%"
echo Parameter 3 is "%par3%"
echo and the rest are "%therest%"
rem.the additional double-quotes in the above echoes^
    are intended to visualise potential whitespaces
```

The remaining arguments in `%therest%` might not look like the way they were originally concerning the delimiters (remember the command line interpreter also treats TABs, `,`, `;`, `=` as delimiters as well as all combinations), because all delimiters are replaced by a single space here. However, when passing `%therest%` to some other command or batch file, it will be parsed correctly.

The only limitation I encountered so far applies to arguments containing the caret character `^`. Other limitations (related to `<`, `>`, `|`, `&`, `"`) apply to the command line interpreter itself.

Comment: +1 because it works for the stuff I have on hand, and it doesn't delve into what I might call batch voodoo. It is still more verbose than the other answer though and a bit harder to see how it works. Can you expand on the alluded circumstances where this will handle things better than FOR?

Comment: Thanks! The `FOR` implementation features only space and tabs as delimiters while the command line interpreter also allows `, ; =` (and there might still be more?). You should replace the portion `"tokens=1-3*"` with `"tokens=1-3* delims=,;=_ "` to reflect that (the `_` stands for a TAB). Anyway, the interpreter does not treat a double-quoted delimiter character (e. g., `" "`, `","`) as a delimiter, but `FOR` does; so the arguments `A B" "C` are interpreted as 2 arguments `A` and `B" "C` by the interpreter, and as 3 arguments `A` and `B"` and `"C` by the `FOR` implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the explication. I finally read (with attention) the link to near duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761615/is-there-a-way-to-indicate-the-last-n-parameters-in-a-batch-file and see your answer is a fleshed out version of @Joey's over there. Readers should read the other answers too; there's another take on using `for` that could be useful

Comment: I encountered another difference in behaviour between the command line interpreter and the `FOR` variant: the latter absorbs twice as much adjacent carets `^` if such are contained in the arguments: when using the interpreter method, you need at least 2 `^^` to get `^` in the output, `^^^^` to get `^^`, etc.; with `FOR`, you need at least `^^^^` to get `^`,etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SET REST=
::# Guess you want 3rd and on.
CALL :SUBPUSH 3 %*
::# ':~1' here is merely to drop leading space.
ECHO REST=%REST:~1%
GOTO :EOF

:SUBPUSH
SET /A LAST=%1-1
SHIFT
::# Let's throw the first two away.
FOR /L %%z in (1,1,%LAST%) do (
  SHIFT
)
:aloop
SET PAR=%~1
IF "x%PAR%" == "x" (
  GOTO :EOF
)
ECHO PAR=%PAR%
SET REST=%REST% "%PAR%"
SHIFT
GOTO aloop
GOTO :EOF
```

I like to use subroutines instead of `EnableDelayedExpansion`. Above is extract from my dir/file pattern processing batch. Don't say this cannot handle arguments with `=`, but at least can do quoted path with spaces, and wildcards.

Answer (score 1):

One more alternative :-)

some of the other answers did not deal with quotes, or with extra spaces between parameters. Disclaimer: I have not tested this extremely well.

This is all just a workaround for `%*` not being updated after a `shift`   ugg!

I implemented it as a POP starting from the technique by @Pavel-P.

- It relies on the batch parser to remove extra spaces
- It depends on a global variable 'Params'
- `~` removes quotes -- leaving it up to you to re-quote as desired.  Remove the `~` if you don't want that.

```
:PopFirstParam
    @set varname=%~1
    @set %varname%=%~2
    @rem @echo %varname% = '!%varname%!'
    @if '%3' equ '' set Params=&goto :eof
    @call :popone %Params%
@goto :eof
:popone
    @set Params=;;;%*
    @set Params=!Params:;;;%1 =!
@goto :eof
```

Usage:

```
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@set Params=%*
@call :PopFirstParam P1 %Params%
@call :PopFirstParam P2 %Params%
@call :PopFirstParam P3 %Params%
@call :PopFirstParam P4 %Params%
@rem etc . . .
```

Specifically I use it to optionally run commands asynchronously:

```
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@rem set variables that decide what to be run  . . . . 

@call :RunIfDefined doNum1 "Title 1"      mycmd1.exe     some  "params"   here
@call :RunIfDefined doNum2 "MyTitle 2"    mylongcmd2.exe some  "params"   here
@call :RunIfDefined doNum3 "Long Title 3" mycmd3.exe     some  "params"   here
@goto :eof

:RunIfDefined
    @set Params=%*
    @call :PopFirstParam DefineCheck %Params%
    @if not defined %DefineCheck% goto :eof
    
    @call :PopFirstParam WindowTitle %Params%
    @call :PopFirstParam Command %Params%
    @rem %Params% should now be the remaining params (I don't care about spaces here)
    @echo start "%WindowTitle%" "%Command%" %Params%
    @start "%WindowTitle%" "%Command%" %Params%
@goto :eof
```

```
C:\test> set doNum1=yes
C:\test> set doNum3=yes
C:\test> call dothings.bat

start "Title 1" "mycmd1.exe"     some  "params"   here
start "Long Title 3" "mycmd3.exe"     some  "params"   here
```

too bad DOS doesn't have a #include