# Sourcetree custom action $FILE

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I've been trying to generate a custom action in Sourcetree that goes over a set of selected unstaged files and performs some function on them. My action is setup to use $REPO and $FILE which in the description says:

"$FILE: the path of the selected ***file(s)*** within the repository"

I'm running the action through a .bat file which looks something like this:

```
@echo off

call "<python path>" "...\myFile.py" --repo=%1 --file=%2
```

Then the python script should run all my important logic.

My issue is that when I select multiple files in Sourcetree and run the action, only one of them is passed into the batch file. How do I make it so I get all the selected files and not only one?

Answer (score 0):

Not very familiar with batch or how command line arguments come in. After a bit of trial and error discovered that the arguments come in as %1, %2, %3, etc. Using %* would give me all of them.

Then did some extra research to get everything after %1 and found this: [batch parameters: everything after %1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935609/batch-parameters-everything-after-1)

So inside of the batch file I added this

```
set _tail=%*
call set _tail=%%_tail:*%1=%%
```

Then, I passed %tail% into --file and that seems to work. I guess I could also just get all of them with %* and split them up in the python side-- this is fine for now.