# How to pass a list of strings to a batch-script as a parameter?

Tags: batch-file

My batch script is used to process a list of strings and I would like to parameterize it so it will accept this list as a parameter from the user.

This is how my code is processing this list currently:

```
set QUEUES=cars plans others
FOR %%q IN (%QUEUES%) DO Call :defineQueues %%q
```

How should I pass this list to the `QUEUES` varibale as a parameter?

For example, how should I pass it to this script:

```
myScript.bat ?
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to enclose your string with quotes:

```
myScript.bat "cars plans others"
```

Then `%1` will be equals to `"cars plans others"`

Or `%~1%` to remove the quotes and only get `cars plans others`

Otherwise, you will get 3 different parameter values:

```
myScript.bat cars plans others

%1 => cars
%2 => plans
%3 => others
```

Answer (score 2):

Excuse me. I read this question and I can't resist the temptation of clarify a couple points about it.

A Batch file usually receive several *words* as parameters, like these ones:

```
myScript.bat cars plans others
```

Previous Batch file receive 3 parameters that may be processed via %1, %2 and %3 in the usual way. If you want that a single parameter receive *several words*, all of them must be enclosed in quotes:

```
myScript.bat "cars plans others"
```

Previous Batch file receive *one parameter* that contain several words that may be processed via %1. Note that the following lines are exactly the same than previous examples:

```
set QUEUES=cars plans others
myScript.bat %QUEUES%
```

Previous Batch file receive *3 parameters*, and:

```
myScript.bat "%QUEUES%"
```

... previous Batch file receive *one parameter*.

---

A *list* is a variable that contain several values separated by spaces, like this one:

```
set QUEUES=cars plans others
```

You may pass this *list* to the Batch file as parameter this way:

```
myScript.bat QUEUES
```

Previous Batch file receive one *parameter* that is a *list* variable. To process the values of the list in myScript.bat, use this method:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR %%q in (!%1!) DO echo %%q
```

---

An *array* is a variable comprised of several elements identified by a numeric subscript, like this one:

```
set NAMES[1]=cars
set NAMES[2]=plans
set NAMES[3]=others
```

An array usually have a simple way to know the number of elements in it; for example:

```
set NAMES.length=3
```

You may pass this *array of strings* to the Batch file as parameter this way:

```
myScript.bat NAMES
```

Previous Batch file receive one *parameter* that is an *array*. To process the elements of the array in myScript.bat, use this method:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /L %%i in (1,1,!%1.length!) DO echo !%1[%%i]!
```

Comment: Thanks for the precise clarification about it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you only pass your QUEUES values on the command line, you can use the %* batch file operator, which is a wildcard reference to all the arguments on the line.

```
@echo off
FOR %%q IN (%*) DO echo %%q
```

Executing the batch file as follows:

```
x.bat cars plans others
```

gives the output:

```
C:\junk>x.bat cars plans others
cars
plans
others

C:\junk>
```

If you pass any other arguments on the command together with the QUEUES elements, [it is not that simple to 'shift' the other arguments out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9363080/how-to-make-shift-work-with-in-batch-files).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm passing several parameters. Good to know anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can call it as `myScript.bat %QUEUES%`
and you can use below code to fetch it in your `myScript.bat` :

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR %%q in (!%1!) DO echo %%q
```

Comment: When posting code, consider using proper formatting: code should be indented by 4 spaces, in-line code should be enclosed in "`".

Comment: @Ivan Thanks for correcting the formatting. I am new here, just started helping others

Answer (score 0):

If you want to let your script be used in this way:

```
myScript.bat "cars plans others"
```

You can try to program in this way:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set string_of_strings = (%~1) // %1 is: "cars plans others", %~1" is: cars plans others", (%~1) is: (cars plans others)
for %%i in %string_of_strings% do echo %%i%NL%
```

The key is, %1 is of string but string_of_strings is kind of string[].