# Ignore question mark in .bat batch scripts

Tags: batch-file, scripting

The thing is that I need to pass one parameter with question marks in it to a .bat batch file. If I use the question mark the parameter is not well passed. How can I solve this?

I'm having troubles with this line:

```
script.bat /n"output.owl" /r"http://www.address.com/blog/?feed=rss2"
```

`=` symbol might be a problem too.

Comment: What exactly are you referring to? Using the simple batch "echo %1 %2 %3" I had no problems with the command line "test.cmd abc? ?def e?fg". All parameters were passed and printed correctly, so I don't quite understand your problem here.

Comment: Still appears to work without problems? What is your batch trying to do? Can you share the code? Maybe the problem lies somewhere else than parameter parsing.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the issue here is the original batch file is using a for loop to
process the command line options, and the question mark is being used for
filename wildcard expansion.

```
> type fortest.bat
@echo off
for %%a in (%*) do (
   echo arg is %%a
)
> fortest a b c/?d
arg is a
arg is b
```

Using positional parameters %1 and %2 avoids the wildcard expansion
done in the for ... (%*) loop.  The shift operator avoids the wild card
expansion as well, if an unknown number of parameters need to be processed.

```
> type shifttest.bat
@echo off
:loop
    if "x%1" == "x" goto :eof
    echo arg is %1
    shift /1
    goto :loop
> shifttest a b c/?d
arg is a
arg is b
arg is c/?d
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always just trap for the ? within your batch file and display an appropriate message to the user.

[This is a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-to-pass-command-line-parameters-in-batch-file) that will help you which has already been asked.