# How do I disable a Pylint warning?

Tags: python, pylint

I'm trying to disable warning C0321 ("more than one statement on a single line" -- I often put `if` statements with short single-line results on the same line), in Pylint 0.21.1 (if it matters: astng 0.20.1, common 0.50.3, and Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 15 2010, 16:22:56)).

I've tried adding `disable=C0321` in the Pylint configuration file, but Pylint insists on reporting it anyway. Variations on that line (like `disable=0321` or `disable=C321`) are flagged as errors, so Pylint *does* recognize the option properly. It's just ignoring it.

Is this a Pylint bug, or am I doing something wrong? Is there a way around this?

I'd really like to get rid of some of this noise.

Comment: There is a good [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29562085/1431079) if you want to disable a single line of code, not all errors of a kind.

Answer (score 237, accepted):

`pylint --generate-rcfile` shows it like this:

```
[MESSAGES CONTROL]

# Enable the message, report, category or checker with the given id(s). You can
# either give multiple identifier separated by comma (,) or put this option
# multiple time.
#enable=

# Disable the message, report, category or checker with the given id(s). You
# can either give multiple identifier separated by comma (,) or put this option
# multiple time (only on the command line, not in the configuration file where
# it should appear only once).
#disable=
```

So it looks like your `~/.pylintrc` should have the `disable=` line/s in it inside a section `[MESSAGES CONTROL]`.

Comment: Thanks, but it already does, in the [MESSAGES CONTROL] section as shown above. Still ignored.

Comment: @Head Geek: well, it works for me. `~/.pylintrc` with two lines, `[MESSAGES CONTROL]` and `disable=C0321`. That prevents that message.

Comment: Odd... the exact same version of PyLint?

Comment: @Head Geek: 0.21.3, astng 0.20.3 and common 0.52.1 actually (the latest when I installed it, more recent than yours)

Comment: If you want to have a project specific pylintrc, make sure to name it `pylintrc` otherwise the location will need to be specifically stated.

Comment: I used `pylint --generate-toml-config >> pyproject.toml`

Answer (score 272):

Starting from Pylint v. 0.25.3, you can use the symbolic names for disabling warnings [instead of having to remember all those code numbers](https://docs.pylint.org/faq.html#do-i-have-to-remember-all-these-numbers). E.g.:

```
# pylint: disable=locally-disabled, multiple-statements, fixme, line-too-long
```

This style is more instructive than cryptic error codes, and also more practical since newer versions of Pylint only output the symbolic name, not the error code.

A disable comment can be inserted on its own line, applying the disable to everything that comes after in the same block. Alternatively, it can be inserted at the end of the line for which it is meant to apply.

If Pylint outputs "`Locally disabling`" messages, you can get rid of them by including the disable `locally-disabled` *first* as in the example above.

Comment: But putting `# pylint: disable=foo` inlyne  makes me line too long, so now I need to add `, line-too-long`! Tongue-in-cheek; this was what I needed and solves my issue. Thanks!

Comment: We might diverge here from the initial question, about general user preference,
 hence would be better addressed by a global configuration file.

 As I prefer seeing in my code what could trigger warnings, for my current use-case,
 I opted for a line-scoped message disabling,
 using the message code to avoid the `line-too-long` issue.

 The correspondance can be found locally with a command like
`pylint --list-msgs | grep <code or keyword>`

 See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67532305/2219061) for details, as a comment needs too stay short.

Comment: The link provided by @omni is dead. You can type `pylint --list-msgs` to list all strings

Comment: https://gist.github.com/omniproc/965bb613177dd4fa896b815aa0e0e365

Answer (score 205):

I had this problem using **Eclipse** and solved it as follows:

In the *pylint folder* (e.g. `C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\pylint`), hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>, right-click and choose to open the windows command in that folder. Type:

```
lint.py --generate-rcfile > standard.rc
```

This creates the `standard.rc` configuration file. Open it in Notepad and under `[MESSAGES CONTROL]`, uncomment
`disable=` and add the message ID's you want to disable, e.g.:

```
disable=W0511, C0321
```

Save the file, and in Eclipse → *Window* → *Preferences* → *PyDev* → *pylint, in the arguments box, type:

```
--rcfile=C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\pylint\standard.rc
```

Now it should work...

---

You can also **add a comment** at the top of your code that will be interpreted by Pylint:

```
# pylint: disable=C0321
```

---

**[Pylint message codes](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/all-codes)**.

---

Adding e.g. `--disable-ids=C0321` in the arguments box does not work.

All available Pylint messages are stored in the dictionary `_messages`, an attribute of an instance of the `pylint.utils.MessagesHandlerMixIn` class. When running Pylint with the argument `--disable-ids=...` (at least without a configuration file), this dictionary is initially empty, raising a KeyError exception within Pylint (`pylint.utils.MessagesHandlerMixIn.check_message_id()`.

In Eclipse, you can see this error-message in the Pylint Console (windows* → *show view* → *Console*,  select Pylint console from the console options besides the console icon.)

Comment: No, it really shouldn't. 1) It references Eclipse, which is irrelevant to the question asked 2) It recommends disabling through the legacy message codes. I would recommend [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23542817/955014) for the simplest solution to the problem, or [Chris Johnson's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32672068/955014) for more details.

Comment: -1 Creating a global configuration file is harmful as it will impact all users of the system. If anything this should be a per-user configuration file, or even better, a project specific configuration file.

Answer (score 111):

To disable a warning locally in a block, add

```
# pylint: disable=C0321
```

to that block.

Comment: This is a legacy technique and is no longer recommended. See the other answers.

Comment: You mean one should use the symbolic name instead of the code number, yes?

Comment: Yes. The [answer by imolit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23542817/832230) covers exactly this.

Comment: How does one find the symbolic name?  My editor will spit out ```[pylint] C0111: Missing method docstring```, so finding the code number is easy, but finding the symbolic name means I have to look it up.

Comment: @AdamParkin I found my messages here: http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/all-messages

Comment: Another way to find symbolic names: grep on the code#, like: $ pylint --list-msgs | grep C0321

Comment: Note that Visual Studio Code is now displaying the symbolic name instead of error code.

Comment: Thanks this worked in Github actions where i had to disable import errors.

Answer (score 91):

There are several ways to disable warnings & errors from Pylint.  Which one to use has to do with how globally or locally you want to apply the disablement -- an important design decision.

**Multiple Approaches**

1. In one or more `pylintrc` files.

This involves more than the `~/.pylintrc` file (in your $HOME directory) as described by Chris Morgan.  Pylint will search for rc files, with a precedence that values "closer" files more highly:

- A `pylintrc` file in the current working directory; or
- If the current working directory is in a Python module (i.e. it contains an `__init__.py` file), searching up the hierarchy of Python modules until a `pylintrc` file is found; or
- The file named by the environment variable PYLINTRC; or
- If you have a home directory that isn’t `/root`:

  - `~/.pylintrc`; or
  - `~/.config/pylintrc`; or
  - `/etc/pylintrc`

Note that most of these files are named `pylintrc` -- only the file in `~` has a leading dot.

To your `pylintrc` file, add lines to disable specific pylint messages. For example:

```
[MESSAGES CONTROL]
disable=locally-disabled
```

2. Further disables from the `pylint` command line, as described by Aboo and Cairnarvon.  This looks like `pylint --disable=bad-builtin`.  Repeat `--disable` to suppress additional items.
3. Further disables from individual Python code lines, as described by Imolit.  These look like `some statement # pylint: disable=broad-except` (extra comment on the end of the original source line) and **apply only to the current line**. My approach is to always put these on the end of other lines of code so they won't be confused with the block style, see below.
4. Further disables defined for larger blocks of Python code, up to complete source files.

   - These look like `# pragma pylint: disable=bad-whitespace` (note the `pragma` key word).
   - These **apply to every line after** the pragma.  Putting a block of these at the top of a file makes the suppressions apply to the whole file. Putting the same block lower in the file makes them apply only to lines following the block. My approach is to always put these on a line of their own so they won't be confused with the single-line style, see above.
   - When a suppression should only apply within a span of code, use `# pragma pylint: enable=bad-whitespace` (now using `enable` not `disable`) to stop suppressing.

Note that disabling for a single line uses the `# pylint` syntax while disabling for this line onward uses the `# pragma pylint` syntax. These are easy to confuse especially when copying & pasting.

**Putting It All Together**

I usually use a mix of these approaches.

- I use `~/.pylintrc` for absolutely global standards -- very few of these.
- I use project-level `pylintrc` at different levels within Python modules when there are project-specific standards.  Especially when you're taking in code from another person or team, you may find they use conventions that you don't prefer, but you don't want to rework the code.  Keeping the settings at this level helps not spread those practices to other projects.
- I use the block style pragmas at the top of single source files.  I like to turn the pragmas off (stop suppressing messages) in the heat of development even for Pylint standards I don't agree with (like "too few public methods" -- I always get that warning on custom Exception classes) -- but it's helpful to see more / maybe all Pylint messages while you're developing.  That way you can find the cases you want to address with single-line pragmas (see below), or just add comments for the next developer to explain why that warning is OK in this case.
- I leave some of the block-style pragmas enabled even when the code is ready to check in.  I try to use few of those, but when it makes sense for the module, it's OK to do as documentation.  However I try to leave as few on as possible, preferably none.
- I use the single-line-comment style to address especially potent errors.  For example, if there's a place where it actually makes sense to do `except Exception as exc`, I put the `# pylint: disable=broad-except` on that line instead of a more global approach because this is a strange exception and needs to be called out, basically as a form of documentation.

---

Like everything else in Python, you can act at different levels of indirection.  My advice is to think about what belongs at what level so you don't end up with a too-lenient approach to Pylint.

Comment: For the most part I cannot advocate using a global nonempty `~/.pylintrc`. IMHO, the configuration should typically be tied to the project, and so it must be somewhere within the project. Only then can it be version controlled and shared with the project. Failing this, a clone may lack the customizations necessary for pylint to exit without printing messages.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson The prefix `pragma ` seems totally unnecessary. For example, I have `# pylint: disable=missing-docstring` in the top of my file, and it applies to the entire remainder of the file. Please check and remove the `pragma` prefix from your answer.

Comment: Pylint FAQ doesn't write about any pragma. (http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/faq.html#is-there-a-way-to-disable-a-message-for-a-particular-module-only): 
you can disable or enable (globally disabled) messages at the module level by adding the corresponding option in a comment at the top of the file:
# pylint: disable=wildcard-import, method-hidden
# pylint: enable=too-many-lines

Comment: Pragma is discussed in the “Messages control” section of that documentation.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson, the `# pylint: ...` comments are ***called*** pragmas, but there is no need to ***write*** `# pragma pylint`. The word pragma does not have any special meaning In Python like it does in C/C++. I think this is confusing in your answer and hope you will update it. For the rest: great answer 

Answer (score 33):

This is a [FAQ](https://docs.pylint.org/en/latest/faq.html#is-it-possible-to-locally-disable-a-particular-message):

> **4.1 Is it possible to locally disable a particular message?**
>
> Yes, this feature has been added in Pylint 0.11. This may be done by
> adding
> `# pylint: disable=some-message,another-one` at the desired
> block level or at the end of the desired line of code.
>
> **4.2 Is there a way to disable a message for a particular module only?**
>
> Yes, you can disable or enable (globally disabled) messages at the
> module level by adding the corresponding option in a comment at the
> top of the file:
>
> ```
> # pylint: disable=wildcard-import, method-hidden
> # pylint: enable=too-many-lines
> ```

You can disable messages by:

- numerical ID: `E1101`, `E1102`, etc.
- symbolic message: `no-member`, `undefined-variable`, etc.
- the name of a group of checks. You can grab those with `pylint --list-groups`.
- category of checks: `C`, `R`, `W`, etc.
- all the checks with `all`.

See [the documentation](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/technical_reference/features.html) (or run `pylint --list-msgs` in the terminal) for the full list of Pylint's messages. The documentation also provide a nice [example](https://docs.pylint.org/en/latest/user_guide/message-control.html) of how to use this feature.

Answer (score 30):

You can also use the following command:

```
pylint --disable=C0321  test.py
```

My Pylint version is 0.25.1.

Comment: This is now a legacy technique. Use of the symbolic name of the disabled warning is recommended instead. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23542817/832230).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with the `--py3k` flag either :(

Comment: Interestingly enough, it works fine if supplied in the `rc` file, and (more troubling) it actually generates a correct `rc` file with `--generate-rcfile`.  Gotta love code with multiple branches that do the same thing :(

Answer (score 19):

You just have to add one line to disable what you want to disable.

E.g.,

```
#pylint: disable = line-too-long, too-many-lines, no-name-in-module, import-error, multiple-imports, pointless-string-statement, wrong-import-order
```

Add this at the very beginning of your module.

Comment: Or in front of the line who is generating the message if you don't want to generalize.

Answer (score 5):

In case this helps someone, if you're using [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code), it expects the file to be in UTF-8 encoding. To generate the file, I ran `pylint --generate-rcfile | out-file -encoding utf8 .pylintrc` in [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell).

Answer (score 4):

As per **Pylint** documentation, the easiest is to use [this chart](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/message-control.html):

- C convention-related checks
- R refactoring-related checks
- W various warnings
- E errors, for probable bugs in the code
- F fatal, if an error occurred which prevented Pylint from doing further processing.

**So one can use:**

```
pylint -j 0 --disable=I,E,R,W,C,F YOUR_FILES_LOC
```

Answer (score 4):

*Sorry for diverging a bit from the initial question, about poster's general preference, which would be better addressed by a global configuration file.
But, as in many popular answers, I tend to prefer **seeing in my code what could trigger warnings**, and eventually **inform contributors** as well.

My comment to [answer from @imolit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23542817/2219061) needs to stay short, here are some details.*

For `multiple-statements` message, it's probably better to disable it *at block or module level,* like this

```py
# pylint: disable=multiple-statements
```

My use-case being now `attribute-defined-outside-init` in a unittest setup(), I opted for a *line-scoped* message disabling, using the message code to avoid the `line-too-long` issue.

```py
class ParserTest(unittest.TestCase):
   def setUp(self):
       self.parser = create_parser()  # pylint: disable=W0201
```

The correspondance can be found locally with a command like

```
$ pylint --list-msgs | grep 'outside-init'
:attribute-defined-outside-init (W0201): *Attribute %r defined outside __init__*
```

Of course, you would similarly retrieve the symbolic name from the code.

Answer (score 1):

Python syntax does permit more than one statement on a line, separated by semicolon (;). However, limiting each line to one statement makes it easier for a human to follow a program's logic when reading through it.

So, another way of solving this issue, is to understand why the lint message is there and not put more than one statement on a line.

Yes, you may find it easier to write multiple statements per line, however, Pylint is for every other reader of your code not just you.

Answer (score 1):

My `pylint` kept ignoring the `disable` list in my `.pylintrc`. Finally, I realized that I was executing:

```bash
pylint --disable=all --enable=F,E,W
```

which was overriding the `disable` list in my `.pylintrc`.

The correct command to show only Fatal, Errors, Warnings, is:

```bash
pylint --disable=C,R
```

Answer (score -2):

Edit "C:\Users\Your User\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json"
and add 'python.linting.pylintArgs' with its lines at the end as shown below:

```
{
    "team.showWelcomeMessage": false,
    "python.dataScience.sendSelectionToInteractiveWindow": true,
    "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
    "powershell.codeFormatting.useCorrectCasing": true,
    "files.autoSave": "onWindowChange",
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--load-plugins=pylint_django",
        "--errors-only"
    ],
}
```