# Disabling some messages when using Pylint in Django

Tags: python, django, pylint

I'm using the django-jenkins plugin in my Django project and it seems that it has installed pylint. I can run pylint byt running `python manage.py pylint`. It works just fine but I would like to disable some messages e.g. w0614. I can't seem to pass this as parameter to pylint using the `manage.py`. Could anyone of you tell me how I can quiet those W0614 messages?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable a warning by adding a comment to each python file where the warning is raised.

```
# pylint: disable-msg=w0614
```

If you don't want to add the comment to each python file, see the question [How do I disable a PyLint warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341746/how-do-i-disable-a-pylint-warning) for a global solution.

Comment: I added this it __init_.py file in the module but I still get those messages. I also try adding them to the manage.py file but to no avail. Do I need to put this in each file where these errors are reported?

Comment: Yes, I think you need to add the comment to each file where the warning is reported. That's not ideal -- it might take as long as it would to fix the unused imports!

For a global solution, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341746/how-do-i-disable-a-pylint-warning

Comment: That rcfile did it. Cheers Alasdair.

Comment: Great! I've edited the answer to make the link to the other question more obvious.

Answer (score 5):

In newer versions of pylint, the disable-msg has been replaced with 'disable', so the comment should be:

```
# pylint: disable=W0614
```

Or from the command line it would be:

```
--disable=W0614
```

Check the [Messages Control](http://www.logilab.org/card/pylint_manual#messages-control) or [Command line options](http://www.logilab.org/card/pylint_manual#command-line-options) sections of the manual for more details.

Answer (score 4):

You could set the PYLINT_RCFILE to full path to custom pylintrc file or just place pylint.rc in root of your project

Check the default_config_path method code:
https://github.com/kmmbvnr/django-jenkins/blob/master/django_jenkins/tasks/run_pylint.py