# Can Pylint error checking be customized?

Tags: python, pydev, pylint

I am using pydev where I have set up pylint.
The problem is that even inside the comments, pylint reports warnings. I was looking to disable any sort of checking inside any line or a block comment.
Also, I wish to follow camelCase naming convention instead of underscores for variables and arguments in my code.
Is there any way to specify such a rule without inserting my code with any pylint: disable comments?

Comment: Please, don't use camelCase.

Comment: While your comment is justified, I was with a team of mainly java developers and to enhance its maintainability/acceptance, I had to stray from pythonic code.

Comment: In some cases camel case is justified. For example when using PySide or PyQt. It would just look horrible to mix Qt-ish camel case with python underscore-ish style.

Comment: @SumitBisht the rule to trump all rules for code style is "be consistent". therefore you did the right thing :).

Comment: Yes, mixing styles is a big no and actually a sign of code smell. Maintaining consistency in any codebase is the key.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can globally disable warnings of a certain class using

```
pylint --disable=W1234
```

or by using a special PyLint configuration file

```
pylint --rcfile=/path/to/config.file
```

A sample config file is given below:

```
[MESSAGES CONTROL]
# C0111 Missing docstring 
# I0011 Warning locally suppressed using disable-msg
# I0012 Warning locally suppressed using disable-msg
# W0704 Except doesn't do anything Used when an except clause does nothing but "pass" and there is no "else" clause
# W0142 Used * or * magic* Used when a function or method is called using *args or **kwargs to dispatch arguments.
# W0212 Access to a protected member %s of a client class
# W0232 Class has no __init__ method Used when a class has no __init__ method, neither its parent classes.
# W0613 Unused argument %r Used when a function or method argument is not used.
# W0702 No exception's type specified Used when an except clause doesn't specify exceptions type to catch.
# R0201 Method could be a function
# W0614 Unused import XYZ from wildcard import
# R0914 Too many local variables
# R0912 Too many branches
# R0915 Too many statements
# R0913 Too many arguments
# R0904 Too many public methods
disable=C0111,I0011,I0012,W0704,W0142,W0212,W0232,W0613,W0702,R0201,W0614,R0914,R0912,R0915,R0913,R0904,R0801
```

See [the documentation](http://docs.pylint.org) over at [Pylint's dedicated site](http://www.pylint.org).

Comment: Good answer, but there's more to it.  See my answer if you want fine-grained control of pylint across multiple projects and more complex scenarios. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32672068/763269

Comment: I tried `pylint --disable=C0111` on the terminal and got `Usage:  pylint [options] module_or_package`. Did I miss something?

Comment: @MelvicYbanez yes you are literally missing something ;)  You have the `pylint [options]` part but not the `module_or_package` part.

Comment: Links to Pylint's Official site: https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ and GitHub repository: https://github.com/pylint-dev/pylint

Answer (score 20):

As said by cfedermann, you can specify messages to be disabled in a `~/.pylintrc` file (notice you can generate a stub file using `pylint --generate-rcfile` if you don't want to use inline comments.

You'll also see in the generated file, in the [BASIC] section, options like "method-rgx", "function-rgx", etc. which you can configure as you like to support camel cases style rather than pep8 underscore style.

Answer (score 3):

Although this is an old question, it should be mentioned one can now specify their [own regex for matching with names](http://docs.pylint.org/features.html#basic-checker).

Then your regex to match camel case would be something like:

```
[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]{2,30}$
```

Answer (score 2):

[Here is the custom check example](http://%20https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/blob/63eb8c4663a77d0caf2a842b716e4161f9763a16/pylint/checkers/typecheck.py), and [another example easier to understand](https://breadcrumbscollector.tech/writing-custom-checkers-for-pylint/).

I was facing a problem similar to you. The following code is my solution. I customized one checker to forbidden import `datetime.now`. You can take it for reference ：

```
class TestChecker(BaseChecker):
    """
    find the check type in the following url:
    https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/blob/63eb8c4663a77d0caf2a842b716e4161f9763a16/pylint/checkers/typecheck.py
    """
    __implements__ = IAstroidChecker

    name = 'test-checker'
    priority = -1
    msgs = {
        'W0001': (
            'You should not import "%s"',
            'import-datetime-returns',
            'Should not import datetime'
        ),
    }

    def __init__(self, linter):
        super().__init__(linter)
        # I use original pylint's ImportsChecker as a property
        # from  import **
        self.forbidden_import = ['datetime.datetime.now']
        self.forbidden_import_from = ['datetime.now', 'now']
        self.forbidden_import_attribute = ['datetime.now', 'now', 'datetime.datetime.now']

    #the function will be rewrited
    def visit_importfrom(self, node):
        names = [name for name, _alias in node.names]
        for item in names:
            for check in self.forbidden_import_from:
                if item == check:
                    self.add_message('W0001', node=node, args=item)

    def visit_import(self, node):
        names = [name for name, _ in node.names]
        for item in names:
            for check in self.forbidden_import:
                if check == item:
                    self.add_message('W0001', node=node, args=item)

    def visit_attribute(self, node):
        for check_attr in self.forbidden_import_attribute:
            if check_attr == node.as_string():
                self.add_message('W0001', node=node, args=check_attr)


def register(linter):
    linter.register_checker(TestChecker(linter))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I customize `pylint`.

### Using a config file

The first way is where you

- call pylint to generate a template config file
- then you tailor the config file to your needs/wants
- then you put the config file in your the default pylint config file location or always call pylint and specify the config file path

### Using a wrapper script

The second way is where you create a wrapper script that calls pylint and in the wrapper script you have a bunch of lines that look like:

```
pylint \
       ${options_here} \
       --disable=xyz1 \
       --disable=xyz_2 \
       ${more_options} \
       --disable=xyz_N \
       --disable=abc \
       $@
```

Currently I am using the wrapper script approach because I want the issues to be sorted by line number and I did some shell scripting to get that sorting order.

Answer (score 0):

Further to the above answer from pradyunsg, here is another regex for CamelCase:

```
^([a-z]\w+[A-Z]+\w+)
```

*(Taken from PyLint's `spelling.py` checker, found in: `%APPDATA% - Local - Programs - Python - [PythonVersion] - Lib - site-packages - pylint - checkers` folder)*