# How can I modify the value of "too-many-statements" from 50 to 100 in the pylintrc file?

Tags: python, pylint, pep8, pylintrc, pep8-checker

When running Pylint on my file I am getting the following message.

> refactor (R0915, too-many-statements, function) Too many statements (95/50)

I want to set the number of statements a function can have to 100 instead of 50 in order avoid the above message from Pylint.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Pylint error checking be customized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10138917/can-pylint-error-checking-be-customized)

Comment: The answer has the options to specify custom configs too.

Comment: I don't want to disable the check. I want to modify the statement check from 50 to 100.
I had modified the max-line-length from 100 to 120. 
eg: default: max-line-length = 100. modified: max-line-length = 100 = 120. 
Is there any way like that to replace the statement check from 50 statements per function to 100 statements allowed per function?

Comment: That link tells about regex, but I am not able to find how to change 50 to 100 in too-many-statements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pylint works based on configured settings which are default [PEP 8](https://pep8.org/) standards. Now, if customizing them is good or bad can be taken for another discussion, as they are kept like that for a reason. For example, if you have a method with more than 50 lines of code, it simply means that you are increasing the [cyclomatic-cognitive complexities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) as well as making it difficult to [unit test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) and get coverage.

OK, arguments aside, I think the following approach can help you customize the linting rule.

Go to your Python `site-packages` directory (it might be inside the Python installation `Libs` folder or in your virtual environment.

For example, `D:\Python37\Lib\site-packages`

Open a command line here, and navigate to the Pylint directory. Execute the configuration generator like

```
pylint --generate-rcfile > custom_standard.rc
```

Now you will have a file named `custom_standard.rc` in the folder. Let’s copy it to some place around your project, say, `D:\lint_config\custom_standard.rc`.

Open the configuration file. You can see a setting for most of the rules. Now, for your question of number of statements inside a method, find the setting called

```
max-statements=50
```

Change it to:

```
max-statements=100
```

Save the configuration file. Now when you run the Pylint executable, use the option `--rcfile` to specify your custom configuration:

```
pylint --rcfile=D:\lint_config\custom_standard.rc prject_dir
```

If you want to integrate this with your IDE like [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyCharm) there are plugins which allows configuring the same.

**But again!, it is not a good decision to change the PEP 8 :-)**