# Make pylint tolerate Requests

Tags: python, pylint, python-requests

When I test a module that uses [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html), pylint has a fit and claims that the [various members of the Request object](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#main-interface) that I use do not exist. How can I fix this? I already run pylint with the --generated-members=objects option.

For example, this code runs fine:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://github.com/timeline.json')

print response.content
```

But pylint claims the field does not exist:

> ID:E1103  Instance of 'Request' has no 'content' member (but some
>   types could not be inferred)

Comment: You can locally disable pylint warnings using a comment like `#pylint: disable=warning-code`. 
[Here](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/all-codes) you can find a list of codes.

Comment: Could yo show some code and the exact error messages, please?

Comment: @Bakuriu Thanks for the workaround! Does that apply to the entire file, or just below the comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pylint` warning and error messages can be configured.

First of all you can write a `${HOME}/.pylintrc` to disable some messages for all pylint checks. You can generate a default version of this file using the `--generate-rc-file` option.
(See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341746/how-do-i-disable-a-pylint-warning) question for a bit more information).

You can also do the configuration inside the sources analyzed. For example putting some comments at the beginning of the file. This will disable the messages for the whole file.
The comment are in the form: `#pylint: disable=warning-code`, and "warning-code" is one of the list found [here](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/all-codes).

You can also disable messages locally, putting the comment before or on the side of a statement/expression.

For example, this disables the "C0322" warning for the code inside the function:

```
def my_func():
    #C0322 -> no space between operand and operator
    #pylint: disable=C0322
    return a+b
```

While putting the comment on the right disables it for the single line of code:

```
def my_func():
   return a+b  #pylint: disable=C0322
```

I think in your case you could either put a comment at the beginning of the functions that use the `request`, or, if you do not access it many times, you could put a comment on the right of the statements.