# Disabling a pylint warning E501. Nothing is working

Tags: python, pydev, pylint

I know this question has already been asked but none of the solutions I have found are working for me. I want to disable the pylint warning E501, line too long while coding in pydev. I have tried in line comments # pylint: disable=E501 and even #pylint: disable=C3031.

I have made an rc file called standard.rc and put it in the options for pylint in eclipse as described here: 
[How do I disable a Pylint warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341746/how-do-i-disable-a-pylint-warning) and even went into the rc file and changed the maximum number of characters allowed on a line. But no luck at all!

Comment: pylint doesn't have E501 nor C3031 messages, that may be the problem. Also recent release encourage readable name, eg `#pylint: disable=line-too-long`

Comment: Thanks @sthenault. However I also tried that (and just tried again  to double check) and it doesn't work. I did it like this: self.poplt_list = [i for i in self.poplt_list if self.poplt_list.col_alive == 'alive'] #pylint: disable=line-too-long
and I am still getting the error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which PyDev/PyLint versions are you using?

Comment: I have PyDev 3.3.3 and pylint 0.26

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `E501 line too long` error comes from [pep8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/), not [pylint](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/stable/).

You can run it as `pep8 --ignore=E501` to avoid that report (specially if you are already checking long lines with pylint).

Comment: But, how do I ignore more than one error? If I am in editor > code Analysis and i input the argument --ignore=E501,E261 all errors are removed, instead of just those two.

Comment: @ruby74, `--ignore=E501,E261` works for me. Errors of type E501 and E261 are not shown but the rest are. Maybe it's an old version of pep8?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried just cranking up the max-line-length variable to an absurd number?

Example: **`pylint --max-line-length=999`** ...*{rest of the command}*