# Pylint warning only shows up on Jenkins

Tags: python, python-2.7, jenkins, pylint

When I run pylint locally, I don't see the warning.  I really would not expect to see the warning at all.  This occurs on at least 2 different versions of jenkins, currently running the latest version 1.576.  The warning is shown in the UI using the Violations plug-in version 0.7.11 which is the latest.

This is the line of code that is tagged in the warning:

```
request.context.__parent__ = report # pylint: disable=W0201
```

And the warning it gives is 5 copies of W0201

[image: I wouldn't believe it myself, unless I saw it.]

This Warning was also disabled above in the code here:

```
#pylint: disable=R0901, R0904, R0914, W0201
```

Neither approach seems to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the pylintrc file is different between the machines/users.

Try copying your local ~/.pylintrc to your jenkins home folder.

Details for this are in here:
[How do I disable a Pylint warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341746/how-do-i-disable-a-pylint-warning)