# Pylint configuration Issues

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, conventions, pylint

On pylint 1.4.1, Im trying to set the configurations according to my desired python conventions.

with that, I encountered several issues:

1. when using old-style class I get C1001 Warning ("Old-style class defined"), which I want to suppress.

   How can I set pylint to allow this kind of class?
   suppressing C1001 only partially helps (since I also get an error for not having 
   __ init __ function in my class, which I don't want to suppress in every class - it is usefull in new-style classes).
2. when defining:

   ```
   class MyException(Exception):
       pass
   ```

   and in another module defining and using:

   ```
   class MyError(MyException):
       pass
   ```

   I get a warning in pylint, saying:
   W0710: Exception doesn't inherit from standard "Exception" class

   is there a way to set it so it will also check the inheritance hirarchy?
3. is there a way to set my own warning? i.e. not allowing usage of " " for a string (only ' '), or """ """ for docstring (only ''' ''')?

thanks.

Comment: For issue 3 I suggest you check out existing question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36490128/force-string-format-in-pylint.

Comment: For issue 1 I suggest you ckeck out existing question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341746/how-do-i-disable-a-pylint-warning

Answer (score 1):

Regarding 1, this is python 2.7 specific so I guess you moved toward python 3 but if not at least you should upgrade to the latest python 2.7 compatible pylint (>1.9,<2).

Regarding 2, this is a bug and it has been fixed in latest version of pylint.

Regarding 3, [you can create your own checker](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/how_tos/custom_checkers.html) or in this case use an existing one using `pip install pylint-quotes`