# How to make pylama complain about single quotes?

Tags: python, lint, pylama

Is there a way to make pylama complain about the project using single quotes and recommend to change it to double quotes?

In my project, we use many single quotes and we decided to use double quotes. We have a pylama.ini file in the project and we would love to put this rule to pylama to check it, but reading its documentation, I cound't find a way to put this rule over there.

Comment: pylama wraps several other tools. Your question amounts to checking the documentation of all these tools and also how to pass configuration for these tools from pylama.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36490128/force-string-format-in-pylint