# pylint: configuration to disable certain warnings

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use vscode with pylint for my Python needs. It works quite well but one thing I don't like is some of the python complaints. E.g:

1. Invalid variable names. In short methods or short loops (< 5 lines). I use one character variable names like `d` for dict and `l` for line.
2. Missing doc string.

Coding style argument aside, I'd like an option to turn this off. It looks like I can do this with pylint command line option. But I'd like to make it into configuration that can be reflected in vscode.

How can I do that?

Comment: pylint has a command line option `--rcfile=[filename]` that lets you customize lots of things with a config file.  The default file is huge but reasonably well documented.

Answer (score 4):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32672068) helpful on setting up a config file.

Basically, add the following to a .pylintrc file in your home directory.

```
[MESSAGES CONTROL]
disable=C0103
```

Answer (score 4):

You might want to edit `settings.json` add the list of rules to ignore, in the attribute `python.linting.pylintArgs`.

```
 "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--disable=Cxxxx"
 ],
```

For example, I am using pep8, and I want to disable E501, as I don't want to restrict to 79 character lines. List of pep8 error codes can be found [here](https://pep8.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.7.x/intro.html#error-codes).

My settings.json looks like this:

```
{
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
    "python.linting.pep8Enabled": true,
    "python.linting.pep8Args": [
        "--ignore=E501"
 ],
}
```

You can refer to vscode documentation on python linting [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_pylint).

Comment: Why is pylintEnabled set to false?