# Redefining a function with pylint

Tags: python, lint, pep8

I have the following at the top of my file/module which says how various types are defined (sort of like a declaration in a C file):

```
Env = dict  # The Interpreter environment is a map of {key: value}
```

And then below in the actual meat of the code I redefine `Env` like so:

```
class Env(dict):
    "An environment dict, containing the parent Env (or None) where created."
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
    # etc.
```

Pylint gives me the following warning:

> function-redefined: class already defined line 16

I understand why it is giving this, but it is intentional in the above case. What would be the suggested way to deal with this? Doing something like the following seems to be the most **expedient** way (but then I find my files are just littered with all these comments every other line if I apply this "let's-dismiss-this-one-here" philosophy), but what would someone suggest in this particular case?

```
class Env(dict): # pylint: disable=function-redefinition
```

Additionally, what is the name for doing the `# pylint:` thing called? (Comment/Annotation/Pragma/?)

---

Additionally, here is a useful thread about type redefinitions in `mypy`: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1191.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I disable a Pylint warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341746/how-do-i-disable-a-pylint-warning)

Comment: So what is the problem now?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I'm wondering for someone who uses linting, do they just litter their code with every time they want to silence a one-off warning with the comments? Or, from someone with experience using `pylint` what might be a good way to address this in a more holistic approach...let's see what some python developers have to say.

Comment: The answers I've linked list numerous other options. I'm sure you haven't evaluated them all within 2 minutes.

Comment: @mkrieger1 which one addresses function-redefinition? That's the question I'm asking.

Comment: @mkrieger1 but yes, thank you for the link. I'm reading those now, actually... (Seems to answer the more 'general' question, but not the specific case)

Comment: Why do you use `Env = dict` in the first place if you redefine it later? If you don't do that the whole problem goes away.