# Pylint Missing Module Docstring. Unable to disable

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

With every new project i have the same issue with pylint "Missing module docstring warning"

I have already tried adding to settings.json

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--load-plugins=pylint_django",
        "--errors-only",
        "--disable=C0111"
    ]
```

and creating .pylintrc

```
[MASTER]
disable=
    C0114, # missing-module-docstring
```

The only working solution is to add to EVERY file. But that is tedious. is there a better way?

```
# pylint: disable=missing-module-docstring
```

[image: With every project]

Comment: Facing a similar problem, did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

For your reference,

```
C0114: missing-module-docstring
C0115: missing-class-docstring
C0116: missing-function-docstring
```

Add all of them to `"python.linting.pylintArgs"` in **User Settings.json** then reload window, see if it helps.

Comment: not helping( tried all variations could think already.  "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--load-plugins=pylint_django",
        "--errors-only",
        "--disable=C0111,C0114,C0115,C0116"
    ]

Comment: no matter what i specify, still showing error.  tried "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--load-plugins=pylint_django",
        "--disable=C0114"

Comment: The settings.json does not seem to be taken into account, maybe something is wrong with ``"python.linting.pylintArgs": `` ?

Comment: @BogdanMind. Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341746/how-do-i-disable-a-pylint-warning) helps?

Comment: Did anyone find a fix?  That setting doesn't work for me either.. VS code doesn't recognize it.  Also would rather have it all in .pylintrc -- is that not possible?