# how to disable linter in pylsp?

Tags: neovim, python-language-server

My neovim(0.6.1) use nvim-lint manage pylint, use pylsp for completion.

When edit a python file, use numpy, scipy etc, the code competion, hover, signature is slow, and cpu use 100%. The code have same lint notion twice. I want disable linter in pylsp, but it not work. How can i do?

This is my config: pylsp.lua

```
opts = {
    cmd = { "pylsp" },
    filetypes = { "python" },
    root_dir = function()
        return vim.fn.getcwd()
    end,
    single_file_support = true,
    configurationSources = {""},  -- default is pycodestyle
    rope = {extensionModules = "", ropeFolder = {} },
    plugins = {
        jedi_completion = {
            enabled = true,
            eager = true,
            cache_for = {"numpy", "scipy"}
        },
        jedi_definition = {
            enabled = true,
            follow_imports = true,
            follow_builtin_imports = true,
        },
        jedi_hover = { enabled = true },
        jedi_references = { enabled = true },
        jedi_signature_help = { enabled = true },
        jedi_symbols = { enabled = true, all_scopes = true, include_import_symbols = true },
        preload = { enabled = true, modules = {"numpy", "scipy"} },
        mccabe = { enabled = false },
        mypy = { enabled = false },
        isort = { enabled = false },
        spyder = { enabled = false },
        memestra = { enabled = false },
        pycodestyle = { enabled = false },  -- not work
        flake8 = { enabled = false },
        pyflakes = { enabled = false },
        yapf = { enabled = false },
        pylint = {
            enabled = false,
            args = {
                "-f",
                "json",
                "--rcfile=" .. "~/.pylintrc"
            }
        },
        rope = { enabled = false },
        rope_completion = { enabled = false, eager = false },
    },
}
pylsp.setup(opts)
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to disable `pylst` linters in `lspconfig` setup:

For example, if you use the [`suggested configuration of nvim-lspconfig`](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig#suggested-configuration), you can change the `lspconfig.pylsp.setup` and configure any plugin you like:

```lua
-- Mappings.
-- See `:help vim.diagnostic.*` for documentation on any of the below functions
local opts = { noremap=true, silent=true }
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', '<space>e', '<cmd>lua vim.diagnostic.open_float()<CR>', opts)
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', '[d', '<cmd>lua vim.diagnostic.goto_prev()<CR>', opts)
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', ']d', '<cmd>lua vim.diagnostic.goto_next()<CR>', opts)
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', '<space>q', '<cmd>lua vim.diagnostic.setloclist()<CR>', opts)

-- Use an on_attach function to only map the following keys
-- after the language server attaches to the current buffer
local on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
  -- Enable completion triggered by <c-x><c-o>
  vim.api.nvim_buf_set_option(bufnr, 'omnifunc', 'v:lua.vim.lsp.omnifunc')

  -- Mappings.
  -- See `:help vim.lsp.*` for documentation on any of the below functions
  vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, 'n', 'gD', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.declaration()<CR>', opts)
  vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, 'n', 'gd', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.definition()<CR>', opts)
  vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, 'n', 'K', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.hover()<CR>', opts)
  vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, 'n', 'gi', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.implementation()<CR>', opts)
  vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, 'n', '<C-k>', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.signature_help()<CR>', opts)
  vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, 'n', '<space>wa', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.add_workspace_folder()<CR>', opts)
  vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, 'n', '<space>wr', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.remove_workspace_folder()<CR>', opts)
  vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, 'n', '<space>wl', '<cmd>lua print(vim.inspect(vim.lsp.buf.list_workspace_folders()))<CR>', opts)
  vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, 'n', '<space>D', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.type_definition()<CR>', opts)
  vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, 'n', '<space>rn', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.rename()<CR>', opts)
  vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, 'n', '<space>ca', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.code_action()<CR>', opts)
  vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, 'n', 'gr', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.references()<CR>', opts)
  vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, 'n', '<space>f', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.buf.formatting()<CR>', opts)
end

require('lspconfig').pylsp.setup {
  on_attach = on_attach,
  flags = {
    -- This will be the default in neovim 0.7+
    debounce_text_changes = 150,
  }
  settings = {
    -- configure plugins in pylsp
    pylsp = {
      plugins = {
        pyflakes = {enabled = false},
        pylint = {enabled = false},
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Hope it works!

Comment: so, your answer is to use pyright instead of pylsp? This doesn't make a lot of sense

Comment: Sorry, forgot to replace it from the suggested configuration for lspconfig. Now it should use pylsp while disabling pyflakes and pylint.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still having this issue there is linting being through pycodestyle. it appears from the pylsp github page (https://github.com/python-lsp/python-lsp-server#installation) that pylint is disabled by default but the pydocstyle is no which provides a load of errors and warnings if your quite "loose" with coding as i am. to disable this within my config i did the following:

```
local lspconfig = require("lspconfig")

-- configure python server
lspconfig["pylsp"].setup({
  capabilities = capabilities,
  settings = {
    pylsp = {
      plugins = {
        pylint = { enabled = "false" },
        pyflakes = { enabled = "false" },
        pycodestyle = { enabled = "false" },
      }
    }
  },
  on_attach = on_attach,
})
```

so if you are using Mason to do linting with pylint and you have the pylsp working also then you may get a lot of errors and some of those might appear multiple times. a good video/videos to watch on lsp and linting that helped me is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ybUE4D80XSk&t=1382s&ab_channel=JoseanMartinez and also https://youtu.be/NL8D8EkphUw. My code fits his example he showed in that later video nicely where he uses pyright, i use pylsp instad. The specific part of that later video where he does this is 26:38.
you can also setup options for keeping linting with pylsp and/or pylint but disabling certain error messages like "line to long" (who hasn't got more than 80 chars of screen to use?) that is done similar to this above code but in the linter config, i use nvim-lint (dude only briefly mentions this in the videos):

```
local pylint = require("lint").linters.pylint
pylint.args = {
  "-f",
  "--disable=C,R",
}
```

this comes from the post : [How do I disable a Pylint warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341746/how-do-i-disable-a-pylint-warning/67532305#67532305)
additional info here: https://docs.pylint.org/faq.html#can-i-give-pylint-a-file-as-an-argument-instead-of-a-module