# PyLint : Suppress a certain error message

Tags: python, warnings, pylint, pylintrc

I am using the pylint module to scan a python module and I am getting a warning similar to this :
`Module 'module_py' has no 'TaskImplementation' member`
I am not using any pylintrc file as I am giving all the arguments from the command line
Is there a way to suppress all occurrences of this message using the command line arguments ?
Thank you !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I disable a Pylint warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341746/how-do-i-disable-a-pylint-warning)

Answer (score 0):

Launch pylint with `--disable=no-member`

> --disable : Disable the message, report, category or checker with the given id(s). You can either give multiple identifiers separated by comma (,) or put this option multiple times (only on the command line, not in the configuration file where it should appear only once). You can also use "--disable=all" to disable everything first and then re-enable specific checks. For example, if you want to run only the similarities checker, you can use "--disable=all --enable=similarities". If you want to run only the classes checker, but have no Warning level messages displayed, use "--disable=all --enable=classes --disable=W".

https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/configuration/all-options.html#disable