# How to Set Single Quotes and Disable Newline at the end using .pylintrc?

Tags: python, pylint

I have been trying to configure my `.pylintrc` file to enforce the use of single quotes and disable the newline at the end of the file. I have read through the available documentation and attempted to find solutions on Stack Overflow, but I couldn't locate a clear answer.

### Error:

When I run with the configuration provided below, I encounter the following error.

```bash
.pylintrc:1:0: E0015: Unrecognized option found: quotes, missing-final-newline (unrecognized-option)
```

### Code:

Below is the snippet of my current `.pylintrc` file:

```ini
[FORMAT]

# Attempt to set single quotes (this causes errors)
quotes = single

# Attempt to disable newline at the end of the file (this causes errors)
missing-final-newline = False
```

I am not sure it right configurations.

### Environment:

- Operating System: Windows 10
- Pylint version: 3.0.3
- Python version: 3.11.4

### Expected Output:

I expect Pylint to enforce the use of single quotes and not insert newline at the end of file in my code.

### Additional Information:

I have tried to find information in the Pylint documentation but couldn't locate details on the `.pylintrc` file for these specific settings. I have also searched on Stack Overflow and tried to resolve the issue through interactions with ChatGPT.

Comment: Shouldn't disabling rules be in a separate block, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4341833/3001761

Comment: Where is the `quotes=single` checker documented? Did you perhaps mean [`inconsitent-quotes`](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/messages/warning/inconsistent-quotes.html)? It would give a warning if you were to mix single and double quotes.

Comment: You are aware that `pylint` won't modify your source files for you but only report issues? There are other tools (e.g. autopep8, black, ruff) that will do so. Maybe you're looking at the wrong tool BTW, the final newline is required by POSIX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to get a valid `.pylintrc` is to have it generated by [`pylint <your options> --generate-pylintrc > .pylintrc`](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/configuration/index.html). The linked documentation states that it's better to rely on the defaults and put only your non-default options in there. That's what you should do.

You can edit the file and remove all the lines you don't want. Or generate a default config and `diff` with yours.

This should give you an idea of the syntax to use in `.pylintrc`. You'll see that all the [command line options](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/configuration/all-options.html) can be used *without the leading hyphens*. So `--disable=foo` on the command line becomes `disable=foo` in the file.

Speaking of `disable`, that's one line you want to have in your `.pylintrc` to disable the check for a missing newline at the end of a file. (Note: it will not remove the newline, or complain if there is one. It will just not-complain when it's not there.)

I couldn't find anything to force single quotes, the closest option seems to be [`--check-quote-consistency`](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/configuration/all-options.html#check-quote-consistency) which is a Boolean option. It will complain if single and double-quoted strings are used in the same file.

It seems every `pylintrc` needs at least one section to put options in but otherwise, it gets ignored. I couldn't find anything on it. Either stick with the section names from the default or create your own.

Putting it all together, we get a `.pylintrc` like this one:

```ini
[MY OPTIONS]

check-quote-consistency=yes
disable=missing-final-newline
```