# Is there a global pylint configuration?

Tags: python, windows, pylint, pylintrc

I want to set some pylint settings globally but I don't know if there is an global pylint configuration or where it is...

I know there is an .pylintrc file but it's not a global configuration.

So my question is how to set pylint settings globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pylint is meant to be set up per python module, so it is always suggested to have it per module, instead of having it globally, so that you can track these files in git.

Comment: So there is no global config. Ok thanks

Comment: You are correct @user10668212 Please consider marking my answer as accepted, if it helped you :)

Comment: This answer is not correct. Pylint **does** support a global configuration file. See this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15837092/1075152 .