# DOS: Command-Line Argument Validation

Tags: validation, exception, command-line, arguments, dos

Bear with me, it's been a while. :)

What is a good way to validate command-line arguments passed to an MS-DOS batch script?

For example, here is what I want to do:

```
IF "%1"=="" throw "Missing 1st argument: Machine Name"
IF "%2"=="" throw "Missing 2nd argument: File Path"
```

Comment: Actual MS-DOS, or the command processor built into Windows?

Comment: @ChrisV: Thanks. I will retag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-to-pass-command-line-parameters-in-batch-file)

```
IF %1.==. GOTO No1
IF %2.==. GOTO No2
... do stuff...
GOTO End1
:No1
ECHO No param 1
GOTO End1
:No2
ECHO No param 2
GOTO End1
:End1
```