# Postgresql -bash: psql: command not found

Tags: linux, postgresql, psql

I have installed PostgreSQL and it is working ok. However, when I went to restore a backup I got the error `-bash: psql: command not found`:

```
 [root@server1 ~]# su postgres
 [postgres@server1 root]$ psql -f all.sql
 bash: psql: command not found
 [postgres@server1 root]$
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: This can happen on CentOS when you accidentally install PostgreSQL 8.4 (package `postgresql-server`) after installing PostgreSQL 9.2 (package `postgresql-server92`) on the same machine. If you erase PostgreSQL 8.4, yum also removes the postgres bin directory from the path.

Comment: ^^ THIS! Thanks Iain

Answer (score 28, accepted):

perhaps psql isn't in the `PATH` of the postgres user. Use the [locate](http://www.linfo.org/locate.html) command to find where psql is and ensure that it's path is in the `PATH` for the postgres user.

Answer (score 52):

```
export PATH=/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin:$PATH
```

The program executable `psql` is in the directory `/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin`, and that directory is not included in the path by default, so we have to tell our shell (terminal) program where to find `psql`. When most packages are installed, they are added to an existing path, such as `/usr/local/bin`, but not this program.

So we have to add the program's path to the shell PATH variable if we do not want to have to type the complete path to the program every time we execute it.

This line should typically be added to theshell startup script, which for the bash shell will be in the file `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Would you be willing to expand this comment?  It seems popular, but it could be much more useful with additional information (for example, where do the above lines go, and what do they do?)

Comment: If you are on Mac and installed Postgres.app, then 

``` export PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:$PATH ```
or 
```
export PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/bin:$PATH```

Comment: @ChauskinRodion thank you so much! this thing was literally killing me

Answer (score 16):

The question is for linux but I had the same issue with git bash on my Windows machine.

My pqsql is installed here:
`C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin\psql.exe`

You can add the location of `psql.exe` to your Path environment variable [as
described in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4822435/1175496), and shown in the screenshot below:

[image: add psql.exe to your Path environment variable]

After changing the above, **please close all `cmd` and/or `bash` windows, and re-open them** (as mentioned in the comments @Ayush Shankar). If you are using an IDE like Visual Studio Code, please close and re-open the  entire IDE (as mentioned in the comments @Somraj Chowdhury)

You might need to change default logging user using below command.

```
psql -U postgres
```

Here `postgres` is the username. Without `-U`, it will pick the windows loggedin user.

Comment: Moreover, if you still see that is is not working , then close the cmd/bash and open a new windown(not tab) of cmd/bash.

Comment: When using vscode, I had to close and re-open the IDE itself (not just closing the integrated terminal sessions) to get the `psql` command working.

Comment: This worked for me even with a newer version, I just installed Postgress 16 and my path was not updated after install

Answer (score 13):

It can be due to psql not being in PATH

```
$ locate psql
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/psql
```

Then create a link in /usr/bin

```
ln -s /usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/psql /usr/bin/psql
```

Then try to execute psql it should work.

Answer (score 5):

In case you are running it on **Fedora** or **CentOS**, this is what worked for me (PostgreSQL 9.6):

In terminal:

```
$ sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers
```

modify the following text from:

```
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

to

```
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin
```

exit, then:

```
$ printenv PATH

$ sudo su postgres

$ psql
```

To exit postgreSQL terminal, you need to digit:

```
$ \q
```

Source: https://serverfault.com/questions/541847/why-doesnt-sudo-know-where-psql-is#comment623883_541880

Answer (score 2):

Check if PostgreSQL is installed or not.

If not you can do the same in ubuntu using this command.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Postgres Mac app (by Heroku) and Bundler, you can add the pg_config directly inside the app, to your bundle.

```
bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin/pg_config
```

...then run bundle again.

**Note:** check the version first using the following.

```
ls /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/
```

Answer (score 1):

there must be two reasons for this either the package is not install or psql is not defined in the PATH

the simple way is to create a link within the /usr/bin or /usr/local/sbin/

First find the the file

```
sudo find / -name psql
```

then create soft link

```
sudo ln -sf /opt/pgpro/1c-14/bin/psql /usr/local/sbin/psql
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we face this issue when the gem installation command doesn't find the `pg` client library for various reasons, such as if `psql` is not in the path.

In those cases, providing the command with the path to `pg_config` may fix the issue.

`gem install pg -v 1.3.5 -- --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config`

In my case, I faced a similar issue when I installed `postgresql@12` with Homebrew in the Rosetta environment.

Following command solved the issue in my case.

```bash
gem install pg -v 1.3.5 -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/Homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@12/12.13/bin/pg_config
```

Answer (score 0):

Run pg-wrapper as root to make the installed client and server programs available via PATH and add SQL man pages to the man page configuration file. This utility is provided in the postgrespro-std-14-client package.

```
/opt/pgpro/std-14/bin/pg-wrapper links update
```

For details on how to handle possible conflicts, see [this](https://postgrespro.com/docs/postgrespro/14/pg-wrapper) description.

Answer (score 0):

After doing an installation on Centos 7.9, I encountered this problem. My finding yielded the following:

- Installation on postgres went to to directory `/usr/pgsql-15`
- Perfoming echo $PATH yielded `/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`

From the output of path above you realise postgresql installation directory is not in  PATH.

Resolution

- Add `/usr/pgsql-15` to PATH on your ~/.basr_profile user file as below:

  `PATH=$PATH:/usr/pgsql-15/bin`

  `export PATH`