# no records showing after migration to postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-migrations, rails-postgresql, pg

Just followed the ["Migrating to PostgreSQL" Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql), migrating my local sqlite3 database to postgres:

here is my database.yml file:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: app_development
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  username: martinbraun
  password:

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: app_test
  pool: 5
  username: mbraun
  password:

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: app_production
  pool: 5
  username: mbraun
  password:
```

My postgres server is running on postgressapp on port 5432. It tells me that it's running and I get connection to my database app_development.

However, "which psql" tells me:

> /usr/bin/psql

and when I start my app, all the records are not loading, I simply see my application layout and all html stuff which is not related to any records. No error is showing up.

I have verified that my database contains data via rails console, so the migration from sqlite3 to postgres was def successful. I am just wondering why my records are not showing and what I do wrong here?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790088/postgresql-bash-psql-command-not-found

Comment: edited my post, actually 'which psql' tells me: /usr/bin/psql
so postgres seems to be there. however, still no records showing up

Comment: did you migrate the data from your sqlite database to your new postgres one too? Otherwise, it will be empty.