# Pip Not recognized as an external command in cmd in windows

Tags: python-3.x, django, installation, pip

When I am trying to install the Python 3.7.1 It installed the Python 3.7.1. I can also check the pip install checkbox. Later I am trying to install pip in cmd. The below error occurs. When I try to see the pip.exe file in Python37/Scripts it shows an empty folder. I don't know what to do and what is the issue. Please help me because it was my study project to do.

[image: This is the root folder image]

[image: This is Scripts folder]

Comment: uninstall python and while installing add python to path [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34900042/11602126)

Comment: type pip --version in cmd and see if pip is there cause if you are using python 3.7 or later it installs pip automatically.

Comment: @ngawangIt Shows that error in cmd when i type the pip --version. in research i see 5 executable pip files,but i dont have it...and also i installed so many times but not solved

Comment: @Pavankumar i am done that process so many times.It does not  show any executable files in that folder but others they have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pip is not setup during installation, you can re-run the python installer and make sure to check the option to install pip or simply access pip using:

```
python3 -m pip
```

All commands are the same,so you can install packages like:

```
python3 -m pip install cython
```

Hope this works for you!