# I wanna (import youtube_dl) . so I Execute the <py -m pip install youtube_dl> but I don't understand this error code

Tags: python, youtube

WARNING: The script youtube-dl.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\PARK\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

Comment: AND i using visual studio code

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error and the installation should work as intended. The warning says that that path is not added to the PATH environment variable.

It is suggested to add Python to the PATH environment variable, read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34900042/why-would-i-add-python-to-path) and this article on [Why you should add Python to path and How to](https://medium.com/@omoshalewa/why-you-should-add-python-to-path-and-how-58693c17c443#)