# No module named 'mlflow.sklearn'; 'mlflow' is not a package

Tags: python, scikit-learn, mlflow

I installed `mlflow` on my Windows machine with

```py
pip install mlflow
```

followed by other dependent libraries such as `pandas`, `numpy`, `sklearn`.

I ran a tutorial on wine quality model from the give link
https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/tutorials-and-examples/tutorial.html

I am getting the error as follows:

```
import mlflow.sklearn
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mlflow.sklearn'; 'mlflow' is not a package
```

I thought it may be some firewall issue, so I tried on my personal system, and it's still the same error.

What could be the mistake I am doing here? Or is it some library-related issue I am facing here?

Comment: Are you using any virtual environment? I would suggest to use `python3 -m pip install mlflow` to make sure pip installs mlflow at (presumably) correct path.

Comment: Did you installed sklearn or scikit-learn? and is package installed at correct path of respective interpreter?

Comment: @GodWin i installed sklearn

Comment: @medium-dimensional : Yes i have create a separate miniconda environment

Comment: for `conda install mlflow` PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

Comment: Yes, this worked now, you can please add the answer of miniconda installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you are installing the package at the correct [PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34900042/why-would-i-add-python-to-path).

For example, if you have different versions of Python installed on your computer, installing packages can get a little tricky and thus, [it's recommended to use a virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573587/what-is-the-difference-between-venv-pyvenv-pyenv-virtualenv-virtualenvwrappe?rq=1) to keep packages or different installations properly organised on your computer.

[Since you are using a conda environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73985582/no-module-named-mlflow-sklearn-mlflow-is-not-a-package#comment130634441_73985582), I would suggest to use `conda install mlflow` with [an appropriate channel](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/concepts/channels.html#what-is-a-conda-channel) instead of `pip install mlflow` i.e. **`conda install -c conda-forge mlflow`**.

For more details, please check https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/mlflow.