# How to install sqlite3 on windows 7

Tags: sqlite

I went to http://www.sqlite.org/download.html and i have downloaded sqlite-dll-win64-x64-3150200.zip and when i extracted it gived me two files sqlite3.def sqlite3.dll and I didn't find the sqlite3.exe file so can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The download you're looking for is the `sqlite-tools-*zip`. It contains the command line tools. The others as you note only contain the libraries.

Comment: Thank you, Can you give me hints about the installation process?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/4822427/1015786 to see how to add install a command line program on Windows.