# .Net Console application as a CLI Command

Tags: c#, .net, console, console-application

I want to build make a .Net Console application available globally as a  CLI command. I tried creating a small application, then adding the executable to my path variable. I then referenced the executable name in the console and it was not found.

I did find that I could add a custom verb through .net core, however that really isn't what I was looking for.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you restarted console after appending path variable?

Comment: Yes, I did. Are you thinking that my approach should have worked?

Comment: Yes, if you appended path variable with directory path (as the answers below trying to note you ) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the *directory* of the application to your PATH variable, not the full path including the filename.

For example:

```
c:\users\john\documents\MyPrograms\test.exe
```

would be added to PATH as:

```
c:\users\john\documents\MyPrograms\
```

and then could be used simply as "test" from Command Prompt.

Note that you need to log out of Windows and log back in for your changes to take effect.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add the Directory instead of the .exe.

1. Type Edit environment variables
2. Open the option Edit the system environment variables
3. Click Environment variables... button
4. There yousee two boxes, in System Variables box find path variable
5. Click Edit
6. A window pops up, click New
7. Type the **Directory** path of your .exe or batch file ( **Directory** means exclude the file name from
   path)
8. Click Ok on all open windows and **restart your system**.

See here for more information in AmiNadimi post : ["Register" an .exe so you can run it from any command line in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822400/register-an-exe-so-you-can-run-it-from-any-command-line-in-windows)

Comment: More detailed than my answer :) +1