# Selenium chromedriver PATH error doesn't resolve

Tags: python, selenium, path, selenium-chromedriver

So I've been trying to follow this YouTube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BGU2X5lrz9M) as a quick fun project to introduce myself to selenium, but I've already run into a problem. Whenever I run my code, I keep getting this error: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. I've searched up the problem many times, moved chromedriver.exe to the C:/ directory to make things easier, and did all I can with the enviroment variables and still can't figure this out. Please help me out!
Here's the code I'm running

```
# This bot is made following this YouTube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BGU2X5lrz9M
# All the import crap
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\chromedriver.exe")


class InstaBot:

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    def close_browser(self):
        self.driver.close()

    def login(self):
        global driver
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher")
        time.sleep(2)
        # "//a[@href'accounts/login']"
        # "//input[@name='username']"
        # "//input[@name='password']"


georgeIG = InstaBot("NotGonnaShowToStackOverflow", "NotGonnaShowToStackOverflow")
georgeIG.login()
```

Here's what I've tried with the environment variables.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the video you linked to, the command `pip install selenium` will have handled the addition of the driver to the path.

I'm assuming you have tried to emulate this on windows and you're having trouble understanding how the `PATH` variable is used. [This related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4822427/1196415) discusses how to register a .exe so it is available globally, which may help you.

You cannot register an executable directly in your `PATH` variable as you have done, your `PATH` should only contain directories. Try moving your `chromedriver.exe` file into one of the folders in your `PATH` and run your commands again.

Alternatively, you could create a folder such as `c:\buildtools`, add that to your `PATH` and then put `chromedriver.exe` in that folder and run your commands again.

Comment: I'm 100% sure this worked because I did this and forgot to change the driver to the new directory and it didn't work and then I did Felipe's solution and that worked so yours might have worked too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this setup:

```
# Setup our chrome preferences.
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# Change this variable to the path of the chromedriver you downloaded.
chromedriver = "D:\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome( executable_path = chromedriver, 
chrome_options = chromeOptions )
```

Answer (score 1):

For me personally, it was a matter of restarting the machine after setting my environment variables. I know this sounds crazy, but for me, it worked.

I understand that this question was resolved already. I just thought I'd provide my own input for anyone that comes across this question in the future.