# how can I excute 'ssh' command in php by system()?

Tags: php, windows, ssh

The php code is:

```
system('ssh');
```

And the error information is:

```
'ssh' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

However when I run ssh in cmd,the ssh command is available:

[image]

So how can I excute `ssh` command in php by `system()`?

Comment: Maybe `C:\Users\DELL\ssh`?

Comment: system('C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe') can not work

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the ssh executable is not in the path variable. Try to add the ssh.exe to the environment as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41895179/251719

Comment: But the ssh command is avaiable in cmd。There is an image in the question

Comment: There is a difference between the path variable for the user and the system-wide path variable. If ssh added itself to the user path variable then it might be only available for you in the CMD, but not for other users. I assume that PHP runs with a different user account. So please check, that ssh is known via the system-wide path variable. https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: I added C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH to my system path. But the ssh still can not work by php system('ssh').The error mesage is >'ssh' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.