# How to start your python app by typing youappname: in the browser?

Tags: python, php, web

So I found out that when I type steam: in the browser it starts steam.
Now I am wondering if I could also apply this function to my own work in progress python app.
But after researching I found nothing.
How to add it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822400/register-an-exe-so-you-can-run-it-from-any-command-line-in-windows

Comment: Hi, can you share or explain what you are trying to do? what you have and what is steam? and what you tring to achive, that would be great for others to help you

Comment: Well steam is a applicatication that allows users to buy and play games. You can start steam like a normal application, but when you have steam installed you can also start steam by typing "steam:" in the search bar of a browser. My goal is to start my own python application by typing something like "mypythonapp:" in the search bar.

Comment: @Marcii well for those kind of applicaiton, an application is installed in the system and it is run in system background mostly and a browser plugin in added into the browser. where browser plugin monitor the thing you type in search bar or you click right click like that, and if it recognize something similiar then it send a msg to the system application and tell it to perform some task.

Comment: You need to register a custom protocol handler in the O/S

Comment: Alright, I'll try that out.