# User Input Operation in Windows batch Programming

Tags: input

I want to take input from the user in ddmmyyyy format and when user enters the date in this format then files would move to the respective folder. I tried in the following code but failled.

SET /p **str**=Enter the name of the folder e.g. 30062011:

move C:\Documents and Settings\MyPC\Desktop*_**%str%**.pdf S:**%str%**

Answer (score 1):

What is failing? Move or accepting user input?

I tried following, and I am able to read the user input

```
@echo off
set /P theuserinput="Enter the filename: "

echo %theuserinput%
```

Comment: As in above code, I want to pass the user input as a paramter in the path, for instance, in your given code, %theuserinput% is the variable, so is it possible that I pass this variable as in the move command like: move c:/cdrs/%theuserinput% d:/%theuserinput%                                                        I just want to move the files of a folder for which user entered the date e.g. 30062011 to the folder other folder of the same date???

Comment: anyone who can help in this regard??

Comment: check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-to-pass-command-line-parameters-in-batch-file