# User Input in Windows batch Programming

Tags: windows, batch-file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [User Input Operation in Windows batch Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605242/user-input-operation-in-windows-batch-programming)

I have three folders on my system and same folders are on the remote system. e.g.

```
30062011
22062011
15062011
```

What I want is basically an user input, which will transfer the contents of above folders to other folders of remote system, like if user enters `30062011`, then the contents of this folder (30062011) from my system to the folder (30062011) of remote system should be moved and so on.

Please help.

Comment: Why have you been asking the same question? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605242/user-input-operation-in-windows-batch-programming

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like below:

```
set /P folder=Enter folder name:
```

Then use `%folder%` to copy the entered folder name

PS: You should consider providing sample code of what you had tried. Not just ask questions on what you want accomplished, that is not what Stackoverflow is for.

Comment: Hi Mate, sorry for the inconvinience, I was using the following code, set /P str=Enter Date:   move c:\bpm\%str% z:\bpm\%str%           I am a new user on Stack, so didn't know about the rules. Please consider it.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
echo.
set /P C=Move all files from which folder name?  
move [From path]\%C%\*.* [To path]\%C%\
exit
```

Comment: Let me try and I will tell you, thanks mate