# Passing parameters by reference between scripts

Tags: batch-file, cmd

The article "Passing by Reference" in http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html mentions the following:

> In addition to passing numeric or string values on the command line,
>   it is also possible to pass a variable name and then use the variable
>   to transfer data between scripts or subroutines.

But how do I do it? When I set the value of a variable and pass it's name as in

```
set parm=42
call sub.bat parm
```

how do I use it in `sub.bat`?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-to-pass-command-line-parameters-in-batch-file

Comment: @RachelGallen This is about passing command line parameters, isn't it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Via delayed exapansion

```
@echo off
setlocal
set var1=value1
set var2=value2
call :sub var1
call :sub var2
exit /b

:sub
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo %~1=!%~1!
exit /b
```

-- OUTPUT --

```
var1=value1
var2=value2
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference them by name, 2.bat run from 1.bat will inherit the same environment block, so

1.BAT

```
set parm=42
echo parm is '%parm%'
call 2.bat
echo parm is '%parm%'
```

2.BAT

```
set parm=XXX%parm%XXX
```

Would print:

```
parm is '42'
parm is 'XXX42XXX'
```

(Using `call sub.bat %parm%` would make a copy of `parm` available to sub.bat in `%1`)

Comment: That's clear to me, but the text I cited mentions "passing a variable name" (but without giving an example).

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is very old, but I wanted to clarify something: "Passing by Reference" in this context does *not* mean you're passing a pointer around.

You're literally just passing the *name* of the variable *as a string*, then accessing the variable from the subroutine.

It works because environment variables use dynamic scoping - variables set in the caller are available to the callee, unless it shadows them by using SetLocal and then reusing the name.

```
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "parm=Hello"
call :subroutine parm
REM The below will print "Hello world".
echo "%parm%"
exit /b

:subroutine
REM Now %1 contains the value "parm"
set "%1=!%1! world"
REM Now variable "parm" contains "Hello world"
exit /b
```

If the subroutine uses SetLocal itself, you have to use EndLocal to avoid shadowing the original variable:

```
EndLocal & set "%1=!%1! %local%"
```

But ultimately there's nothing *special* about the value that was passed; it's just a variable name that you use in `set`, which happens to correspond to an existing variable in the outer scope.