# Enable GCC compiler C++11 flag by default on Windows

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, compiler-construction

I am using windows 8.1 and have installed GCC compiler on my machine. Every time I have to compile a c++ file (using c++ 11 features), on the command prompt I need to type g++ file.cpp **-std=c++11**. Is there a way so that I don't need to type -std=c++11 everytime? Also please note that I cannot use make files and the file will always be compiled through command line.

Comment: Can you add alias like g++11 = g++ -std=c++11 ?

Comment: How about using a buildsystem?

Comment: What Development Environment do you use? Eg.: CodeBlocks can be configured to compile c++11 by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a batch file to invoke `gcc` with `-std=c++11` and save it to one of your `PATH` directories

- [How can I pass arguments to a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-to-pass-command-line-parameters-in-batch-file)

Or you should be able to add `-std=c++11` to GCC specs file to effectively change GCC's default configurations.

- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Spec-Files.html

Answer (score 0):

you can create alias and put in .bashrc file
alias g++='g++ -std=c++11'