# How to compile and run (by a single command) a C++ program manually on MS DOS instead of Borland?

Tags: c++, dos, turbo-c++, borland-c++

I do this now by running two commands.

```
C:\TC\Bin>tcc test.cpp
C:\TC\Bin>test
```

Is there any way to accomplish this by using just one command?

Comment: you could make a `.bat` DOS script, e.g. edit a file `mytest.bat` and run just `mytest.bat`

Comment: I could but during the development I have to do this again and again so I want just one command so that this can happen quickly.

Comment: How about `tcc test.cpp & test` ?

Comment: @Michael: it is DOS, not Linux

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: `&` is valid in a `cmd` window.

Comment: @PradyumnShrivastava: about the comment of Basile: you should only make the script once.  If you have different filenames, you can make a script that accepts a filename in the command line (http://stackoverflow.com/a/26702/104774).

Comment: You can also use `doskey` macros... google for details if interested.

Answer (score 1):

As Basile Starynkevitch said you could write a batch file... 
This version has error checking for compile errors...

`@Echo off
tcc test.cpp
if errorlevel 1 goto FAILED
test.exe`

:FAILED

As your project gets more complicated consider using MAKEFILE's

Comment: Might want to add `goto :EOF` after `test.exe`

Comment: why? If compilation fails it goto's eof, if compile is ok the command line will read, parse and ignore the :FAILED label... So no need

Comment: To prevent execution of stuff after `:FAILED` on successful compilation. It's a pretty standard practice in bat-files.

Comment: errr????? there is NO stuff after FAILED... The purpose of going to FAILED is to skip the TEST.EXE line, so no attempt to execute a failed compile takes place (actually it will be the last successful version of the EXE). What would you suggest any code after FAILED does, clear the screen so you can't see the error messages????
The batch file as shown will work perfectly for what the questioner asked for.

Comment: This was a misunderstanding - I thought you intended to have additional stuff there. You are right - it will work as is.