# How to run batch file in cmd with param

Tags: batch-file

So in my code I have smth like this

```
set/p "apk=>> "
```

And I wanna start my script from run window with apk variable:

```
myprogram.bat apk_variable_content
```

Is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass command line parameters to a batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-to-pass-command-line-parameters-to-a-batch-file)

Answer (score 0):

Put `%1` to where you wanna put your parameter - it will pull the first parameter you give it in the command line.
`%2`will take the second one.
And so on, until `%9`

Answer (score 0):

```
myprogram.bat %apk%
```

Inside myprogram.bat

```
echo %1
```