# How do I make my batch file take input without using /p?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to make a batch file that allows me to search for something on wikipedia. But instead of using /p and it asks me for input, I want to to automatically search. For example, I would type search Example, and it would search for example on wikipedia. Thank you in advanced.
P.S. I do not have any code currently, but to clarify I dont want to use /p %input% in the code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass command line parameters to a batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-to-pass-command-line-parameters-to-a-batch-file)

Comment: I need an example. That's too complicated. Sorry if It's a duplicate.

Comment: Save this to a file named `search.bat` and you're done: `@start "" "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search?search=%*"`

Comment: I mean I want to type in what to search for in command and it searches for it. The question you lead me to said something about a /u? Can you give me information on that?

Comment: My previous comment is the solution.  If you prefer, I can post it as an answer below?

Comment: I'm saying I dont want it to take me to the website's search, I want it to be its own search in a way. Like I'd say Search "Example" and it would search for that on the website and take me there. It would also be great if you could post it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save this to a file named `search.bat` and you're done:

```js
@start "" "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search?search=%*"
```

The `%*` means all command-line arguments.  So if, on the command line, you enter

```
search Example
```

The script launches your default web browser and opens the Wikipedia search page for `Example`.  Wikipedia then redirects you either to the corresponding article or the disambiguation page, whichever is more appropriate according to Wikipedia's algorithms.

If you:

```
search snow cream
```

you instantly get taken to the Wikipedia entry for snow cream.