# How to receive variables in batch files through cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm creating a command for cmd for which I need to receive text values from cmd and execute them into the batch file.
The name of the batch file is abc.bat, which is copied in the default folder of my cmd path.

My Command would be like:

```
abc some text
```

ABC.bat looks like:

```
@echo off
echo %x%
```

Now I want variable x to get the value "some text"
So that whenever I execute

```
abc qwerty
```

the command line prints

```
qwerty
```

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-to-pass-command-line-parameters-to-a-batch-file

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `x` variable to hold all of the arguments passed to your script in command line, which is achieved by `%*`, so the code you're asking for is:

```
@echo off
set x=%*
echo %x%
```

Comment: Was successful in making it run :) Thanks for the help!