# How can I pass command line arguments to a program in a Windows batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to do this :

```
cd C:\Users\Public
%1 /s
```

Where %1 is the name of and executable that changes based on a where it's being executed, but is otherwise identical. The issue is that the `/s` is being seen as a command or program and not an argument to the executable passed in `%1`. Is what I'm trying to do possible? If so, what's the syntax?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass command line parameters to a batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-to-pass-command-line-parameters-to-a-batch-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help guys. I looked at the documentation and your comments and, though I'm still completely unsure of how this is actually supposed to work, I got it working sensibly. Here's the solution I came up with:

```
"%~1" /s
```

Comment: If  my or **any other** answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted. [See this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) for an explanation of why this is important.

Answer (score 0):

If you save what you have as testit.bat and then when you go to run it add the parameter after your batch file name: "testit dir" it will run the dir command with the /s switch.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand this, I'm a Unix guy, so Windows batch files are completely foreign to me. If I have a batch file called runit.bat and I type "runit executable" /s the executable will be run with the /s switch? If I am understanding this correctly, what do I do if the argument passed to %1 contains spaces, which will be the case more often than not?

Comment: If you go to a dos prompt in windows (click your start button and in the "Search programs and files" type cmd and push enter).  That should open a dos window.  In that dos window change to the folder where your testit.bat file is located ( cd\users\public ).

Comment: Sorry first change your batch file to %~1 instead of just %1.  Then when you run it type:     testit "dir /p"

Comment: so when you want to run it with your executable name put quotes around the name:   runit "executable"    and it will but /s on the end.

Answer (score 0):

Next example could help.  Note:

- `"` double quotes using: If a single parameter contains spaces, you can still pass it as one item by surrounding in "quotes" - this works well for long filenames: [Syntax : Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html);
- `%*`in a batch script refers to all the arguments (e.g. `%1 %2 %3 %4 %5 ... %255`) but only arguments `%1` to `%9` may be referenced by number: [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

The `cliparsearg.bat` script prints all command line arguments:

```
==>type cliparsearg.bat
@echo OFF >NUL
set /A "ii=0"
:loopfor
    echo param %%%ii% = %0
    SHIFT
    set /A "ii+=1"
if not [%0]==[] goto :loopfor
echo   all %%* = %*
goto :eof

==>cliparsearg.bat withoutspaces /S 3rdPar
param %0 = cliparsearg.bat
param %1 = withoutspaces
param %2 = /S
param %3 = 3rdPar
  all %* = withoutspaces /S 3rdPar

==>cliparsearg.bat with 2 spaces /S 3rdPar
param %0 = cliparsearg.bat
param %1 = with
param %2 = 2
param %3 = spaces
param %4 = /S
param %5 = 3rdPar
  all %* = with 2 spaces /S 3rdPar

==>cliparsearg.bat "with 2 spaces" /S 3rdPar
param %0 = cliparsearg.bat
param %1 = "with 2 spaces"
param %2 = /S
param %3 = 3rdPar
  all %* = "with 2 spaces" /S 3rdPar
```

Resources (basic *required reading* for Windows batch scripters):

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)