# Creating a dynamic .bat file

Tags: batch-file, scripting, automation

I was wondering if I could get some help with regards to writing a batch file that could take user input. (Or guidance if a batch file is not the way to go.)

I usually have a task that I do by opening CMD, navigating to a specific folder and running the following command

rda -v 848 -i "C:\me\rda-tools-1.7.0.Ra1\Input" -o "C:\me\rda-tools-1.7.0.RC1\Output"

Now this task is repetitive, and the only thing that changes each time is the number (848 in my example).

Can you guide me on how to write a batch file that navigates to the specific folder, asks me for that 3 digit number for input and then runs the command above?

Please note I have very little knowledge on batch files.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass parameters to a batch file. They're taken in sequence, from `%1` to `%9` (you can use more, but you have to [shift](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732231.aspx) them to get them into position to use). (Technically, there is a `%0` - it's the full path and filename of the batch file itself.)

For example, put the following into a batch file (for instance, *RunRDA.bat*):

```
@echo off
rda -v %1 -i "C:\me\rda-tools-1.7.0.Ra1\Input" -o "C:\me\rda-tools-1.7.0.RC1\Output"
```

Run it from a command prompt with your version:

```
C:\RDA>RunRDA 848
```

For more information, see [How to pass command line parameters to a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-to-pass-command-line-parameters-to-a-batch-file)

Comment: Nice just tried it. However, this means i have to navigate to C:\RDA every time i want to do this. Is there a way to be able to have a batch file, double click it, be asked the 3 digit number and run the command? (i.e. no navigation)

EDIT- don't mean to sound lazy, just want to involve the least amount of manual steps as possible.

Comment: That's not the question you asked here. :-) Your question was about passing parameters to a batch file from the command line, which was the question I answered. If you now have a different question about how to get a prompt for information from a batch file, first search to see if that's been asked here before; if not, post a new question asking about that topic.

Comment: Of course, thank you for the help Ken. Wasn't aware follow up questions should be created as new threads. Will do!

Answer (score 2):

You can pass parameter to a batch file.
Follow below article on how to pass parameter to a batch file
[How do I pass command line parameters to a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-to-pass-command-line-parameters-to-a-batch-file)