# run the batch file with the defalut arguments using izapck 4.3.5

Tags: java, izpack

I need to run the batch file in izpack 4.3.5 with the deafult properties(arguments like host,path etc).
batch file is in bin folder of IZPACK.

in processSpec.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<processing>
<job name="Say Hello">
<executefile name="bootstrapCCE_v98.bat"> </executefile>
</job>
</processing>
```

in install.xml

i have added processSpec.xml in rsources and tried to run the process panel using installer.

in packs:

```
<file src="bootstrapCCE_v98.bat" targetdir="$installDir">
```

i tried this way but i couldn't able to run the batch file.
Can you please give me simple idea how to run the batch file with custom properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work for you (ProcessPanel):

```
<job name="Starting service">
  <os family="windows" />
  <executefile workingDir="${INSTALL_PATH}/bin/win32" name="${INSTALL_PATH}/bin/win32/service.cmd">
    <arg>-nopause</arg>
    <arg>start</arg>
  </executefile>
</job>
```

I think you can pass just values to the batch file so after that you use them in your batch file in order of appeareance with `%` (e.g. `%1`).
More can be found here [How do I pass command line parameters to a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-to-pass-command-line-parameters-to-a-batch-file)