# Giiving inputs to CMD exe by daynamically

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have an application ,i want to run on using task scheduler .

> > now i want to set up execution through command line arguments on my local system.
> >     i created set up but ask password i need to enter that password dynamically i.e from file are as arguments etc.
> >     Please suggest me any solutions to skip password option or to enter password dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question?  It explains how to call a batch file with command line parameters.

[How do I pass command line parameters to a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-to-pass-command-line-parameters-to-a-batch-file)