# Open file with Batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a file:

```
myfile.txt
```

And a batchfile

```
mybat.bat
```

And I want to open `myfile.txt` with `mybat.bat`.
In mybat.bat, I would have something like this:

```
start "filepath"
```

But, how do I get the file path of `myfile.txt` (The file I opened with the batch file)?

**Edit:** 
What I mean in this question is that when you have .exe files, for example `notepad.exe`, You open files *with* that program. What I would like to do is open a file *with* my batch file, and in the batch file have some code that does something with the file opened with it. So, to do something with the file opened *with* the batch file, I neeed the file path of the file opened *with* my batch file.

Comment: You copy and paste in the file path from Windows Explorer...like `start "C:/path/to/file/myfile.txt"`

Comment: That won't work if I have a file called myfile2.txt, I want it so that ANY file opened with my bat file will be opened. (I don't want a hard-coded value)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass command line parameters to a batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-to-pass-command-line-parameters-to-a-batch-file)

Comment: Open a command prompt window, execute `call /?` and read help of this command explaining how to evaluate parameters of a batch file or a subroutine which both can be called with command __call__.

Comment: Am I the only one struggling to understand what OP wants?  @htmlapps, is the text file in the same directory as the batch script?

Comment: @TheJuniorProgrammer: Note that start takes a title as the first parameter, so it is `start "title" myfile.txt` or `start "title" %1` what OP wants.

Comment: I _think_ you're looking for `for /f "delims=" %%A in (myfile.txt)`

Answer (score 0):

When you open with a batch file, the file path and name is usually passed as the first argument, so you would use `%1` to get the path and name to execute it:

```
@call %1
```

Answer (score -1):

you don't "open" Textfiles with Batch, you read them.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem get filename (given as parameter):
set filename=%1
rem read file line by line:
for /f "delims=" %%a in (%filename%) do (
  set line=%%a
  rem do something with the line:
  set line=!line:e=a!
  rem write (changed) line:
  echo(!line!
)
```

Call your batchfile with the name of the textfile as parameter:

```
mybatch.bat myfile.txt
```