# Running bat file with paramaters

Tags: batch-file

I have bat (`file.bat`) file with the following lines:

```
echo "Upgrading..."
cp %1/global/a-* %2/global/
```

I run in CMD the following:

```
bash file.bat /opt/ad-kf041f /srv/
```

As I understand, it should put the parameters instead of the `%num`, but it doesn't and I get:

```
cp: cannot stat `%1/global/a-*': No such file or directory
```

As you can see, I try the suggestion of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-to-pass-command-line-parameters-to-a-batch-file), but it still gives me the same error.

I also try:

```
set  arg1=%1
echo %arg1%
```

and it prints: `%arg1%`

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass command line parameters to a batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-to-pass-command-line-parameters-to-a-batch-file)

Comment: Try to equal new variable to the `%1` first: `SET PARAM=%1` and then cobcatenate with the var: `%PARAM%/global/a-*`

Comment: You mix up the unix and windows scripts, please specify what kind of script you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the file with `bash`, it's a bash script, not a "batch file". The bash syntax for command line arguments is

```
cp "$1"/global/a-* "$2"/global/
```

Comment: Regardless of whether this is a bash or cmd shell script, it should check, at a minimum, check the exit code to see that the copy worked. Checking to see that the parameters exist before using them would be a good idea as well.