# How to pass command line specific parameters to a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want pass specific parameters(aaa|bbb|ccc) but it's not working.

Here's what the command line looks like:

```
    test.bat aaa|bbb|ccc
```

and test.bat looks like:

```
    echo %1
```

but its not working cuz test.bat receive only 'aaa'. 
how can I pass whole parameter 'aaa|bbb|ccc'?

ps. I must use this format : 'aaa|bbb|ccc'
there is no option to change like aaa_bbb_ccc.. etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass command line parameters to a batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-to-pass-command-line-parameters-to-a-batch-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the "|" means you use the pipe function.
http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html

You should use **"aaa|bbb|ccc"** so that it will read everything between the quotation marks.

I hope it helps

Comment: ... and `echo %~1` to remove the quotes, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

The VERTICAL BAR is the pipe character to command.com and cmd.exe. If you want to use is literally, it must be escaped using a CARET.

```
K:>echo aaa^|bbb^|ccc
aaa|bbb|ccc
```

Actually, I think I might prefer the quoting suggestion as it appears to work under bash and perhaps other shells.

```
$ echo "aaa|bbb|ccc"
aaa|bbb|ccc

$ echo 'aaa|bbb|ccc'
aaa|bbb|ccc
```

Comment: @user3460334 - Please mark one of the responses as the "Answer." That's how the SO community works.