# How to read VS 2015 publish output path

Tags: project, publish

I'm running a batch file from Visual Studio during the AfterPublish event. I'm doing a file system publish, and having trouble with the second parameter as in:

```
<Exec Command="$(SolutionDir)\PostBuildEventPublish.bat &quot;$(ProjectDir)&quot; &quot;$(ProjectDir)&quot;" />
```

I really need the second parameter to point to the output path where I specified to publish to. The above line works now since I wanted to test if the batch file was working in the first place but now I need the batch file to work against where I'm publishing to.

Thanks much for any help

Answer (score 0):

See this answer: [How to pass command line parameters to a bath file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-to-pass-command-line-parameters-to-a-batch-file)

If you are passing the parameters in the right way, then maybe there is a problem with your bath code.

Comment: I mentioned that the exec statement that I had works fine as a test but now I need the second parameter to specify where the publish folder is located at.  Its definitely not the ProjectDir.

Comment: so, the bat file works from command line, but is not working in another place, I don´t get whole thing, can you be more specific ?

Comment: I'm no longer going this route. Im working with the latest bits from the .NET Core build of Aurelia. Thanks all.