# How to run a c# console app with arguments from a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, console-application

i'm working on creating a batch file to run c# console execution file which on it , i connect to CRM with 3 params : the url , login and then password

My issue is that i couldn't write the bat code , i found this example every where

```
@echo off C:\Users\xxx\appname.exe %param1 %param2 %param3
```

i save my bat file but when i open it nothing is happened is it supposed to open window like cmd? how could i found my console success notes that i mentioned in my code? Please help

Comment: Why would that work. Stop finding and start reading. This is abusive.

Comment: This isn't even related to C#. Batch files and parameter syntax is explained TechNet, Windows Help, numerous duplicate questions like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-to-pass-command-line-parameters-to-a-batch-file)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put it on two lines, because they are two commands:

```
@echo off
C:\Users\xxx\appname.exe %param1 %param2 %param3
```