# Windows Batch: using user input as command argument

Tags: windows, batch-file, youtube-dl

I recently discovered [youtube-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) and I wanted to make a batch file within the folder of the youtube-dl executable that asks for a url and uses that url in the

```
youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 -i -o songs\%(title)s.%(ext)s <video URL>
```

command, which saves the video as an mp3 file in the \songs\ folder in the same filepath as the executable. The command works fine if I copy-paste it into a command prompt and replace `<video url>` with the actual url, but when I try to put this in a batch file (e.g. with `set var1=""`) it uses the variable's name in the command (`youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 -i -o songs\%(title)s.%(ext)s var1`).

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551/how-do-i-pass-command-line-parameters-to-a-batch-file), and it seems to be what I'm looking for, but it didn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When copying the command into a batch file, you'll need to replace `%` with `%%`, so that the output template parameter to the `-o` option will be interpreted correctly (i.e. as the string `%(title)s.%(ext)s`).

If you prefer to be prompted to enter the link, batch file may look like this:

```
set /p var1=  "Enter youtube link: "
youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 -i -o songs\%%(title)s.%%(ext)s %var1%
```

Or, just set `var1` before calling the script (`set var1=youtube-link`), or in the script itself.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!